# Qual a prioridade do HTML? "id" ou "class"?

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber se o HTML trata por prioridade o `id` ou `class`.

Por exemplo, se eu estou montando minha estrutura e faço o seguinte:

```
<div class="teste1" id="teste2">TESTE</div>
```

O que ele vai fazer? Aceitar o que foi declarado primeiro? No caso o `class`. Se eu tivesse feito o inverso, seria o `id`?

E o `!important` é relevante nisso também?

Comment: Você pergunta o que foi declarado primeiro no CSS?

Comment: Não. Pergunto o que o HTML irá aceitar primeiro.

Comment: Não sei se entendi, o HTML não tem que aceitar nada, até porque ele aceita os dois. Vou tentar responder o que eu acho que é possível responder. Se você não entender, você comenta e tento melhorar.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## HTML

No HTML você sempre poderá ter ambos e **nenhum terá prioridade sobre o outro**. Não importa quais sejam eles. As duas informações são diferentes com funções diferentes, por isto elas coexistem e no exemplo postado elas não conflitam. Então ambos são aplicados sem problemas. O problema ocorre quando o mesmo nome é usado para os dois atributos. Tenha isso em mente. Vou mostrar abaixo o que acontece quando há conflito no CSS.

Lembro que `id` deve ser único para todo documento, mas `class` pode ser repetido para vários elementos e um elemento pode ter mais que uma classe (nem todos sabem disto). Em outras palavras não pode existir mais de um elemento com o mesmo ID, mas pode haver quantos elementos você quiser com a mesma classe. Ou seja, o ID é um identificador único do objeto do documento e a classe é um marcador para dizer que aquele objeto possui determinadas características, possivelmente em comum com outros objetos do documento. Fazendo uma analogia (meia-boca) com as perguntas aqui no SOpt pense no `id` como sendo o título do objeto, e o `class` como sendo *tags* para o objeto.

Você só deve usar ambos se tiver um motivo para usar. Na verdade não coloque nenhum destes atributos no objeto se ele não for útil para alguma coisa.

## CSS

No CSS vai tratar cada um individualmente. Para definir o estilo para o `class` no CSS você fará com a diretiva `.` (iniciando com ponto). Para o `id` a diretiva usada é o `#`. Tudo que dá para fazer com um dá para fazer com o outro em termos de estilos no CSS.

Se tiver definição conflituosa para ambos **o `id` terá prioridade sobre `class`** (não seria o caso do seu exemplo). Pense, é mais provável que você queira dar um estilo mais específico para aquele objeto do que um estilo mais genérico, que é o caso da classe que serve vários objetos. O *browser* vai ignorar a classe porque o identificador possui uma definição de estilo que provavelmente se encaixa melhor para o objeto, afinal essa definição foi criada com esta especificidade.

Então o *browser* renderizará usando o estilo do `id`. É ele que será "aceito" em primeiro lugar. Não importa a ordem que ele foi declarado no HTML ou no CSS.

Vou repetir, isto só é relevante quando existem dois estilos com o mesmo nome.

```css
#secao {
    color: #0000FF
}
.secao {
    color: #000000
}
```

```html
<div id="secao" class="secao">Texto</div>
```

O texto terá cor azul e não preta.

O `!important` não afeta nada se não há realmente um conflito entre os dois. Esta diretiva só é útil quando há conflito, quando há duas definições diferentes para a mesma coisa. Veja o que acontece quando usamos ela na classe que conflita com o identificador.

```css
#secao {
    color: #0000FF
}
.secao {
    color: #000000 !important
}
```

```html
<div id="secao" class="secao">Texto</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Important.html).

Se precisa usar `!important` tem grande chance do código estar mal escrito.

## JavaScript

Para o Javascript faz diferença o uso do `id`, você precisa usá-lo para identificar o elemento específico que deseja manipular por código. Inclusive com JS e, é claro, jQuery, você pode até mesmo adicionar uma nova classe para uma elemento mas não pode fazer o mesmo com o `id` sob pena de ter problemas para identificar corretamente com o o que está mexendo.

Mais informações relevantes para ler em [Qual seletor CSS tem prioridade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143850/101)

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente. Passo a usar `id` somente para algo que eu vá fazer com **JQUERY**.

Comment: @FelipeStoker é uma opção. Para JavaScript realmente faz diferença tratar um ou outro.

Comment: Quem negativou provavelmente não vai dizer o que tem errado mas estou aqui para aprender junto.

Answer (score 8):

<sup>As respostas presentes já endereçam bem o assunto, venho apenas complementar as existentes com algumas notas.</sup>

## Sumário

A prioridade das propriedades de CSS num elemento são tratadas da seguinte forma:

Prevalecem as propriedades com a expressão `!important`, depois as que estão atribuídas no `id` que não tenham sido subscritas pela expressão e por último as atribuídas em `class`(s) que não tenham sido subscritas pela expressão ou pelo `id`.

## A exemplificar

Em CSS, a regra é que o [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) é um seletor que tem que ser único na página, muito devido às suas aplicações em JavaScript, motivos os quais facultam ao mesmo uma precedência sobre qualquer [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) presente no mesmo elemento bem como estilos aplicados diretamente na tag desse elemento.

No entanto, convém advertir que a expressão [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) existe para tornar um valor da respetiva propriedade de CSS mais importante que todos os outros, isto independentemente de `id` ou `class`:

```css
div{                    /* estilo na tag */
  color:green;
}
.blue{                  /* estilo via class */
  color:blue;
}
#red{                   /* estilo via id */
  color:red;
}
.grey{                  /* estilo expresso como IMPORTANTE */
  color:grey!important;
}
```

```html
<div>A minha cor via TAG</div>
<div class="blue">A minha cor via CLASS</div>
<div id="red">A minha cor via ID</div>
<div id="red" class="blue">A minha cor via ID + CLASS</div>
<div id="red" class="blue grey">A minha cor via ID + CLASS + !important</div>
<div id="red" class="grey blue">A minha cor via ID + !important +  CLASS</div>
```

De notar que a Mozilla Developer Network considera o uso de `!important` má prática:

> Usando `!important` é uma prática ruim porque torna a depuração difícil, pois você quebrar a cascata natural em suas folhas de estilo.

---

## Combinações

Podemos ainda completar a resposta com a questão das combinações de seletores.

Ao atribuirmos propriedades de CSS a um elemento, podemos atribuir as mesmas via `class`, `id`, `tag`, mas também com uma combinação.

Fica um exemplo de uma combinação com `id` + `class` que prevalece sobre as regras supra citadas, mas não prevalece sobre a expressão `!important`:

```css
div{                        /* estilo na tag */
    color:green;
}
.blue{                      /* estilo via class */
    color:blue;
}
#red{                       /* estilo via id */
    color:red;
}
.grey{                      /* estilo expresso como IMPORTANTE */
    color:grey!important;
}

#red.bubu {                 /* combinação prevalece sobre as regras de ID */
    color:black;            /* ou class com excepção do que tem a expressão IMPORTANTE */
}
```

```html
<div>A minha cor via TAG</div>
<div class="blue">A minha cor via CLASS</div>
<div id="red">A minha cor via ID</div>
<div id="red" class="blue">A minha cor via ID + CLASS</div>
<div id="red" class="blue grey">A minha cor via ID + CLASS + !important</div>
<div id="red" class="grey blue">A minha cor via ID + !important +  CLASS</div>

<div id="red" class="blue bubu">
    <small>A minha cor via ID + CLASS deveria dar vermelho, mas foi subscrito pela combinação "#red.bubu" para preto.</small>
</div>
```

---

## Desambiguação sobre uso do `id`

Fiquei com a ideia que o conceito geral é que: "um `id` não deve ser utilizado para estilos", tal conceito deve ser considerado incorreto e passo a comprovar:

O uso do `id` para estilos em CSS é perfeitamente válido e tem por exemplo a mesma utilidade que o JavaScript lhe dá, ou seja, atingir um elemento especifico na página.

Se os estilos no `id` não fossem válidos, porque teria a W3C perdido tempo a implementar centenas de regras que trazem inúmeros trabalhos aos navegadores que as implementam e aos programadores que as tem que conhecer?

E a resposta pode ser encontrada na documentação:

#### [7.5.2 Elementos identificadores: os atributos id e class](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

> O atributo `id` tem vários papéis em HTML:
>
> Como um seletor de [folha de estilo](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html).
>   Como uma [âncora](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#anchors) de destino para links de hipertexto.
>   Como forma de fazer referência a um elemento particular de um [*script*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#htmlrefs).
>   Como o nome de um elemento [`OBJECT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT) declarado.
>   Para o processamento de propósito geral por agentes do usuário (por exemplo, para a identificação de campos quando extrair dados de páginas HTML em um banco de dados, tradução de documentos HTML para outros formatos, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

O seletor `id` tem maior precedência do que o seletor `class`. Então quando tiver ambos, o `id` sempre será aplicado.

```css
.foo { color: blue }
#intro, #intro1 { color: red }
```

```html
<p class="foo">Hello!</p>
<p id="intro1">Hello!</p>
<p id="intro" class="foo">Hello!</p>
```

Exemplo prático também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtsys/8mbLbkvr/).

**Recomendação:** Evite usar `id` para atribuir estilos, pois o `id` deve ser únicos por página.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>As repostas já estão muito boas, porém estudando sobre encontrei um exemplos que pode facilmente descobrir a predominância</sub>

[A W3C criou uma forma de calcular a especificidade de seletores.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) Para entender de forma simples, basicamente distribuímos pesos diferentes as regras aplicadas:

- `CSS inline`: 1000 pontos;
- `ID`: 100 pontos;
- `Classes, pseudo-classe e atributos`: 10 pontos;
- `Elementos`: 1 ponto.

Na prática, podemos fazer cálculos como os exemplos a seguir:

`p.foobar:` 1 classe + 1 elemento = 11 pontos.

`div#foobar .foo .bar:` 1 ID + 1 elemento + 3 classes = 131

Definas os valores que achar necessário, mas lembre-se que a ordem de predominância está na sequência que descrevi acima.