# Ajuda com HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, xhtml

Preciso criar uma pagina que tem duas perguntas com duas respostas (radio) de SIM ou NÃO, e, embaixo, um botão de enviar.
Preciso que as perguntas e respostas, quando respondidas e o usuário clicar no botão enviar, apareçam em uma TEXTAREA logo abaixo para o usuário copiar e colar em um bloco de notas por exemplo.

Segue o código já criado em HTML com a estrutura:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <p>Pergunta1? 

        <input type="radio"name="escolhaL"value="sim"/>SIM 
        <input type="radio"name="escolhaL"value="não"/>N&Atilde;O
    </p>

    <p>Pergunta2?
        <input type="radio"name="escolhaR"value="sim"/>SIM 
        <input type="radio"name="escolhaR"value="não"/>N&Atilde;O
    </p>

<br>    

        <p> 
            <input type="submit"value="Enviar"/> 
        </p> 

<br>

        <p> 
            <textarea name"mensagem" rows="10" cols="27"></textarea> 
        </p>

</body>
</html>
```

O que não sei fazer é quando clicar no botão jogar as perguntas e respostas selecionadas dentro da TEXTAREA. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: sabe usar JQuery?

Comment: Não sei cara. Comecei a  desenvolver para web a pouco tempo.

Comment: Teria como ajudar?

Comment: Cara, e coisa super simples, mas requer um conhecimento médio, se não posto todo código aqui e mesmo assim não vai funcionar, da uma olhada nisso aqui: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Saberia me dizer qual dessas tags eu uso para fazer o que preciso? Sabendo qual tag é a certa eu me viro para ver como ele é implementada no código.

Comment: Nossa renan e Randrade, ajudaram muito, os dois funcionaram e rodaram perfeitamente, e deu pra entender legal passo a passo de como funciona com a explicação de vocês, ajudaram muito, obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Creio que esta pergunta não é adequada a proposta do site porque não apresentar uma dúvida técnica, mas pede para que seja fornecida uma solução completa para um problema. Por favor observe as regras para publicar perguntas na Central de Ajuda do site.

Answer (score 2):

> Existem algumas formas de fazer isso. Como você é iniciante, irei colocar a forma mais "simples" (que eu encontrei) de se fazer isso, mas não a melhor.

Primeiro, vejamos um exemplo funcional:

```html
<script>
function PreencherCampo(){
    var pergunta1 =  document.getElementById("pergunta1").innerHTML;
    var pergunta2 =  document.getElementById("pergunta2").innerHTML;
    
    var elementos1 = document.getElementsByName('pergunta1'); 
    var resposta1 = '';
     for (i = 0; i < elementos1.length; i++) {
       if (elementos1[i].checked) {
        resposta1 = elementos1[i].value;
     }
    }
    
    var elementos2 = document.getElementsByName('pergunta2'); 
    var resposta2 = '';
     for (i = 0; i < elementos2.length; i++) {
       if (elementos2[i].checked) {
        resposta2 = elementos2[i].value;
     }
    }
    
  document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = pergunta1 + ': ' + resposta1 + '\n'+ 
      pergunta2 + ': ' + resposta2;
}
</script>  
  
  
  <p id="pergunta1">Pergunta1?</p>
        <input type="radio"name="pergunta1"value="Sim" checked/>SIM 
        <input type="radio"name="pergunta1"value="Não"/>Não
    <p id="pergunta2">Pergunta2?</p>
        <input type="radio"name="pergunta2"value="Sim" checked/>SIM 
        <input type="radio"name="pergunta2"value="Não"/>Não
<br>    

        <p> 
            <input type="submit"value="Enviar"  onclick="PreencherCampo()"/> 
        </p> 

<br>

        <p> 
            <textarea name"mensagem" rows="10" cols="27" id="resposta"></textarea> 
        </p>
```

Nesse exemplo, primeiro pegaremos o valor de cada pergunta pelo `id` dos elementos, dessa forma:

```
var pergunta1 =  document.getElementById("pergunta1").innerHTML;
var pergunta2 =  document.getElementById("pergunta2").innerHTML;
```

Após isso, vamos pegar todos os `radios` pelo `name`, e após isso verificar qual está com o atributo `checked` (que indica qual está marcado ou não).

```
var elementos1 = document.getElementsByName('pergunta1'); 
    var resposta1 = '';
        for (i = 0; i < elementos1.length; i++) {
        if (elementos1[i].checked) {
        resposta1 = elementos1[i].value;
        }
    }
```

E fazemos a mesma coisa com o segundo grupo, como o código do exemplo mostra. Se tivéssemos mais, iriamos criar o terceiro e assim por diante.

Após isso, precisamos colocar o valor no `textarea`, e para isso basta obter o elemento (textarea) por `id` e setar o `innerHTML` como o valor que queremos, dessa forma:

```
document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = pergunta1 + ': ' + resposta1 + '\n'+ 
                        pergunta2 + ': ' + resposta2;
```

O por fim, chamaremos a nossa função ao clicar no botão **enviar**, pelo evento [.onclick()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) em nosso botão, desta forma:

```
<input type="submit"value="Enviar"  onclick="PreencherCampo()"/>
```

Com tudo isso, temos o resultado esperado, utilizando apenas [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Eu começaria alterando HTML, use `<div>` e classes para agrupar elementos.

- [Quando devo usar o atributo `class` nos elementos HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117922/4808)

Da forma que está fazendo, terá um trabalho enorme somente para obter o título da pergunta (que é um parágrafo cheio de outros elementos dentro). Use uma tag para manter o título isolado do restante do elemento, já que você vai precisar desse conteúdo textual posteriormente.

Existem várias formas de melhorar isso, a priori deixaria assim:

```
<div class='pergunta'>
   <p>Você vem sempre aqui?</p>
   <input type='radio' name='pergunta1' value='Não'>Não <br>
   <input type='radio' name='pergunta1' value='Sim'>Sim
</div>
```

Isso já vai facilitar você obter todos os elementos que possuem classe `.pergunta` usando [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), se precisar incluir/remover perguntas futuramente, o modo de obtê-las continuará o mesmo.

```js
(function() {

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', copiarPerguntas);


  function copiarPerguntas() {
    
    var $perguntas = document.querySelectorAll('.pergunta'),
        $textarea  = document.querySelector('textarea'),
        length     = $perguntas.length;

    $textarea.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){      
      var pergunta = $perguntas[i];
      var titulo   = pergunta.querySelector('p').innerHTML;
      var resposta = pergunta.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value;
      
      $textarea.innerHTML += titulo + '\n' + resposta + '\n';
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
textarea { width: 400px; height: 100px }
```

```html
<div class='pergunta'>
  <p>Você vem sempre aqui?</p>
  <input type='radio' name='pergunta1' value='Não'>Não <br>
  <input type='radio' name='pergunta1' value='Sim'>Sim
</div>

<div class='pergunta'>
  <p>Essa cantada está "manjada"?</p>
  <input type='radio' name='pergunta2' value='Não'>Não <br>
  <input type='radio' name='pergunta2' value='Sim'>Sim
</div>

<button type='submit'>Enviar</button>

<br>
<textarea></textarea>
```