# Usar tags HTML5 como seletores CSS3 é uma boa prática?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, estilo-de-codificação

Usar os nomes de *tags* HTML5 como a maioria dos seletores CSS é uma boa pratica? Seja por eu não ser criativo para dar nomes para `ids` ou classes, ou por querer deixar o código HTML mais limpo possível, deixando apenas a estrutura e semântica das *tags*.

Desde o meu aprendizado, sempre usei e abusei das *tags* pelo fato de sua semântica, por exemplo no lugar de um `<div id="cabecalho">` usar apenas um `<header>` e coisas desse tipo (`<footer>, <main>, <section>, <aside>` e por ai vai...).

Em alguns fóruns e *posts* em sites de nome (Caelum), li algo que deu a entender que praticar isso deixa seu CSS menos versátil e com grande chances de sua manutenção ser precoce, pois está totalmente preso à estrutura HTML.

Tenho que sempre usar classes e `ids`, optar sempre por *tags* quando for possível ou se existe um meio termo?

Comment: "sites de nome" nesse caso não sei se é uma coisa boa, principalmente por que me parece que seu raciocínio está sendo sensato, e o do site no mínimo duvidoso (agora, pode ser que eles tenham dito outra coisa e sido entendido errado, só lendo o original mesmo). Obviamente que se você tem um `<header>` é desnecessário criar um `#cabecalho` sem motivo. Vá pelo mais simples, curto e objetivo. Complique só se precisar. Quase sempre você vai conseguir deixar o site em ordem com poucas classes e IDs. Normalmente quem enche de identificação à toa em tudo quanto é tag não domina o assunto.

Comment: ah sim, aqui esta o link (http://blog.caelum.com.br/seu-codigo-css-pode-ser-mais-limpo-flexivel-e-reaproveitavel/) da uma lida ve o que acha, mas é esta a ideia, ser o mais simples, por isso fui sensato.

Comment: Já estranhei a primeira frase "Bons programadores aprendem boas práticas de código desde criancinhas.". Não vou falar bem ou mal do site aqui, por mera questão de ética, mas acho que o pessoal pega muita receita de bolo quando deveria explicar as verdadeiras razões de se fazer desse ou daquele jeito. E o mais importante: não tem solução que sirva pra todos os casos, por isso o importante é entender (assim como você fez, perguntando para saber mais) do que comprar idéias prontas de terceiros que a gente nem sabe ao certo quem são.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objetivamente não tem que usar. O uso só se faz necessário quando ele tem um motivo técnico, tem um objetivo em por ele aí. Para entender melhor tem algumas leituras:

- [Qual é a finalidade das propriedades "id" e "name" de uma tag HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127330/101)
- [Qual a prioridade do HTML? "id" ou "class"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39875/101)
- [Quando devo usar o atributo class nos elementos HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117922/101)
- [Boas práticas usando CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/65783/101)
- [O que devo usar no CSS, id ou class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11130/101)

O `id` é quando você precisa de uma estilização específica daquele elemento. E a classe é para um grupo qualquer de elementos, muitas vezes seria todos que usam uma determinada *tag*, aí não tem porque usar.

Então eu vou no meio termo, não use até que precise usar. Não tem como estilizar apenas um elemento pela *tag*, a não ser que tenha certeza que nunca terá outro elemento com a mesma *tag*, aí é risco. É muito comum que o estilo se aplique a todos os elementos daquela *tag*, pelo menos dentro daquela área do documento. Exemplo:

```
<div id="produtos">
    <section>
        <h3>Brinquedos</h3>
```

No CSS só precisa:

```
#produtos h3 { ... }
```

E não há confusão com outros `h3` do documento fora desta `div`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Header.html).

O Bacco já comentou o que eu acho, quanto mais simples, melhor.

O único caso que talvez usaria `id` ou `class` onde pode ser resolvido com a *tag* é quando vai fazer algo para terceiros estilizarem como quiserem. Mesmo assim pensaria muito antes de fazer e tentaria evitar. Ainda dá para deixar as pessoas estilizarem pelas *tags*, mas nem sempre será tão prático.

Não gosto da fonte que consultou isso, acho que lá há muita coisa errada ou com opiniões de complicam demais o desenvolvimento.

Existe um princípio importante que é o [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Não faça algo até precisar. Só tenha certeza que está fácil mudar se preciso.

Considero uma escolha correta. Há quem discorde.

Comment: legal cara, curti bastante sua resposta e entendi, não vou mais me atender muito a coisas que estas fontes falarem daqui em diante. Tambem penso como você, só usar quando for necessário !

Answer (score 0):

Não. Não é uma boa prática. É um erro.
Não estilize por tags.

Você pode por exemplo precisar de 2  num mesmo documento, ai se estilizar:

```
header {

}
```

Vai ter que ficar "brigando" e sobrescrevendo coisas desnecessárias.
Estilize sempre por classe ou id, mas nunca pelo nome da tag.

Quando vc estiliza pelo nome da tag vc está fazendo um "css reset global", em que todas as tags daquele nome terão aquele estilo.
E você pode sim, ter mais de um , ,  numa mesma página, e cada um ter um posicionamento e estilo diferente do outro.

Comment: Se a pessoa tem esses problemas, nem deveria estar mexendo com CSS pra começo de conversa. Saber resolver ambiguidades e usar os seletores é necessidade básica de qualquer um que se meta a mexer com estilização, e as identificações só devem ser usadas quando realmente fazem sentido semântico. Vide a outra resposta. Claro que em sites caseiros, gastar 400 bytes a mais à toa com estilo redundante não faz diferença, mas em qualquer aplicação mais séria o uso somente no contexto certo prevalece.

Comment: Sinceramente, eu não repetiria certas tags em meu código, e pra estas foi que perguntei, eu sei disto, que se eu jogar apenas na tag repete e tal, mas a questão que coloquei é, até quando ids e classes são necessárias mesmo, e acho q ja entendi qual é o meio termo nisso

Comment: Até porque, caso eu tenha `<span class="boxTitulo"><h2>Titulo</h2></span>` por exemplo, no meu css eu estilizaria: `span.boxTitulo h2{ font-size: 18px; }` e não interferiria em mais nenhum `<h2>` na pagina. Isso seria para evitar sair colocando id e class em tudo!

Comment: Sugiro a leitura de arquiteturas CSS, como o SMACSS
https://smacss.com/