# Evento de Mouse sobre Duas telas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma tela com background vermelho, ao clicar sobre ela abre uma nova com 
background azul. Esta tela de background azul deveria acionar um *alert* quando clicar sobre ela, mas não está acontecendo. Alguém poderia me falar?

OBS.: Isso é apenas uma simplificação do meu problema.

```js
$("#botao").click(function () {
   $("#tela").append('<div id="tela2"></div>');
});

$("#tela2").click(function () {
   alert("quero que apareça");
});
```

```css
#tela{
   width: 600px;
   height: 450px;
   background:red;
}

#tela2{
   width: 300px;
   height: 250px;
   background:blue;
}
    
#botao{  
   width:50px;
   height: 45px;      
   background:yellow;      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tela">          
   <div id="botao">BOTAO</div>          
</div>
```

Comment: tentei fazer ,isso mas não consegui Anserson. Nessa tela azul terá outros elementos clicáveis

Comment: Se a sua *simplificação* é fiel ao problema, então deveria resolver. O seu problema é que o `click` não funciona para elementos que são adicionados dinamicamente. Você pode fazer isso com o `on` e passar três parâmetros para ele: evento, seletor do elemento filho e a função *callback*, tal como foi apresentado na pergunta supracitada.

Comment: eu editei a publicação.Adicionei um botão. Que chama a tela 2.É mais próximo do meu problema...E nesta tela 2 terá outros elementos clicáveis

Comment: Você entendeu porque o seu código não funciona?

Comment: Não ... ate agora não consegui solucionar o problema.

Comment: mas agradeço a  ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando a página é carregada, o seu código JS será executado:

```
$("#botao").click(function () {
  $("#tela").append('<div id="tela2"></div>');
});

$("#tela2").click(function () {
  alert("quero que apareça");
});
```

Na primeira parte ele define que quando o elemento `#botao` for pressionado será adicionado o elemento `#tela2` dentro de `#tela`.

Na segunda parte ele define que quando o elemento `#tela2` for pressionado uma mensagem de alerta surja na tela; mas neste momento não existe um elemento `#tela2` na página - ele só existirá depois que `#botao` for pressionado. Ou seja, o evento será adicionado a nenhum elemento e nunca ocorrerá durante a execução da página.

Para resolver isso, você precisa utilizar a função `on`, que consegue informar como segundo parâmetro um seletor filho para receber o evento - mesmo que ele ainda não exista na página. Na verdade, o evento é atribuído ao elemento pai, que verificará sempre quem foi o elemento alvo do clique (essa é a grande diferença entre as funções).

[Qual a diferença entre o .on("click", function() {}) e o .click(function() {})?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction)

```js
$("#botao").click(function() {
  $("#tela").append('<div id="tela2"></div>');
});

$("#tela").on('click', '#tela2', function() {
  alert("quero que apareça");
});
```

```css
#tela {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  background: red;
}

#tela2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue;
}

#botao {
  width: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tela">
  <div id="botao">BOTAO</div>
</div>
```

Veja que com `on`, o evento ficará associado ao elemento pai, `#tela`, mas informamos que só queremos que a função *callback* seja executada se o elemento alvo do clique for o elemento `#tela2`.

> **Nota:** também não faz sentido você adicionar múltiplos elementos na página com mesmo `id`. [Por que é considerado errado/ruim repetir uma ID em HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318255/5878) Tome cuidado com isso também.

Comment: Entendi ...Anderson.Muito bem explicado .Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Toda vez que você cria um novo elemento por javascript, você não consegue acessar ele desse jeito.

O que você pode fazer é deixar o elemento em `display:none` e depois dar um `$("#tela2").show()`.

Ou você pode fazer a função assim:

```
$("div").click(function(e){
    var id = e.currentTarget.id;
    if(id === 'tela'){
        $("#tela").append('<div id="tela2" style="width: 300px;height: 250px;background:blue;"></div>');

    }else if(id === 'tela2'){
        alert("quero que apareça");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ainda não resolveu meu problema...pq nessa segunda tela terei outros elementos que serão clicados

Comment: Nesse caso, você vai ter que mudar sua estrategia. Pq, você ta colocando a div tela como pai, então toda vez que você clicar na filha, você vai tbm clicar no pai. Entende?