# Selecionar mais de uma opção com checkbox estilizado

Tags: css

Estou usando alguns checks estilizados para marcar alguns tamanhos de alguns produtos em um filtro, vendo pelo inspeção do chrome os checks estão lá ao clicar o filtro é realizado, mas na visualização normal não consegui deixar os checks como marcados, não sei onde posso estar errando.

Nessa imagem os checks estão estilizados mas não consigo marcar nenhum e o filtro não é acionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa outra imagem, pelo inspetor, consigo ver os checks e se marcar o filtro é realizado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O site pode ser visto aqui:

[Site em desenvolvimento](http://rendamaislingerie.com.br/index.php)

Comment: essa imagem foi _troll_, hein.. meu chefe levantou pra ver que site eu estou acessando =D

Comment: Minha mulher veio aqui reclamar que agora tem mulher *pelada* no meu "joguinho" :/

Comment: Desculpa ai pessoal, nem me toquei da foto.

Comment: E estado "checado" seria o contorno Preto ao redor do elemento?

Comment: Olá @LeoCaracciolo, veja na segunda imagem, que desmarquei o display:none do input.

Comment: hahaha, vc coloca uma mulher desse jeito e quer que alguém veja checkboxes?

Comment: Pronto, "problema" da foto resolvido.

Comment: Seria isso mesmo @hugocsl, podendo selecionar mais de um check, mas não consegui.

Comment: Tive que ir no histórico das edições pra ver rss...

Comment: Creio que terá que fazer isso via JS. Serve?

Comment: Com CSS só vejo uma forma, e vc tera que tirar o checkbox de dentro do A, e passar o efeito da LI para o A, assim vc faz no css input:checked+a  e coloca a classe

Comment: Olá @sam, nem assim eu consegui, será muito bem vinda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma simulação aqui tentando aproveitar o máximo do seu código. Porém vc precisa fazer algumas mudanças moderadas na sua estrutura do HTML e não sei se isso seria adequado nessa etapa do projeto...

Primeiro vc que para selecionar o `checkbox` clicando em algum elemento esse elemento deve ser uma `<label>` com o atributo `for="idDoCheckbox"` e vc tem que passes os estilos CSS da `<li>` para esse `label` dentro do `<a>`, além disso o `checkbox` deve vir antes do `<a>`

Para entender melhor veja o exemplo abaixo.

```css
.sidepanel {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 14px 18px 7px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.widget_sized ul {
    padding-bottom: 13px;
}
.widget_sized li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.widget_sized a label {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    transition: border 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.widget_sized a label:hover {
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.widget_sized input[type="checkbox"]:checked + a > label {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.widget_sized input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
.widget_sized a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidepanel widget_sized product-data">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="id1" class="item_filter size" value="10">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sizeXS" .="">
    <label for="id1">46</label>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="id2" class="item_filter size" value="10">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sizeXS" .="">
    <label for="id2">48</label>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Hugo, esse <label for="id2"> precisa ser dinâmico?

Comment: Não necessariamente... mas vc só pode ter um for="" para um id="" único, então se vc tem 10 inputs vc precisa de 10 ids diferentes e 10 labels diferentes com um for= para o ID correspondente. Aqui tem uma material sobre os IDs que pode te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318255/por-que-é-considerado-errado-ruim-repetir-uma-id-em-html/ e se tiver mais alguma dúvida é só dar o toque

Comment: Olá Hugo, agora é coisa simples, como posso deixar as linhas, tanto quando passo o mouse e quando seleciono iguais, alterei e não deu certo, tipo, mais fininhas.

Comment: @adventistapr Vc queria deixar a linha so selecionado mais fina é isso? Aqui na resposta eu já editei e coloquei com 1px. Mas ai no seu projeto veja se vc não deixou algum CSS para traz sobrescrevendo esse estilo. Ou então coloca !importatnt no atributo border em último caso... Mas em 30 min vou estar em casa, eu vou dar uma refinada nesse CSS, pq eu peguei direto do link que vc postou na pergunta. Deve ter algum CSS redundante ai atrapalhando o que vc quer fazer.

Comment: @adventistapr cara dei uma formatado nos estilos do CSS da resposta e deixei só o essencial. Outra coisa! Dei uma olhada lá no seu site do link, e reparei que vc ainda está com parte do CSS antigo funcionando em paralelo com esse da resposta. Inclusive a LI ainda está com a borda, acho que é essa borda que vc quer remover `.widget_sized li:hover, .widget_sized li.active { border: 2px solid #333; }`

Comment: Será que posso trocar uma ideia no chat, coisa rápida, mas não sei como fazer

Comment: Chama ai, só que só devo ter un 15 min pra te ajudar pq minha noiva ta chegando na área... Mas pergunta lá que na medida do possível vou te respondendo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83044/discussion-between-adventistapr-and-hugocsl).