# Converter jQuery em Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Estou tendo vários problemas ao converter esse trecho de código com jQuery utilizando apenas Typescript.

```
 function addTourOverlay() {
        if ($('#tour-overlay').length === 0) {
          $('body').prepend('<div id="tour-overlay"></div>');
        }
    resizeOverlay();
  }

  function resizeOverlay() {
    var window_height = $(window).height;
    var window_width = $(window).width;
    $('#tour-overlay').height(window_height).width(window_width);
  }
```

Atualmente a conversão está assim:

```
addTourOverlay2() {
    if (document.querySelectorAll('#tour-overlay').length === 0) {
        let newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
        newDiv.id = 'tour-overlay';
        let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
        newDiv.appendChild(body);
      }
    this.resizeOverlay();
  }

  resizeOverlay() {
    let window_height = screen.height;
    let window_width = screen.width;
    document.getElementById('#tour-overlay').style.height = window_height; 
    document.getElementById('#tour-overlay').style.width = window_width;
  }
```

estou obtendo os seguintes erros:
O tipo 'number' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo 'string'. (linhas 36 e 37)

O argumento do tipo 'NodeListOf' não é atribuível ao parâmetro do tipo 'Node'.
  A propriedade 'baseURI' está ausente no tipo 'NodeListOf'.(linha 28)

Comment: Já corrigi o post, está mais claro e correto agora

Comment: Dada a ausência da palavra `function` para definir a função e o uso do `this` suspeito que esteja definindo isso dentro de uma classe, correto?

Comment: Sim, é uma classe

Comment: Calma, agora que eu vi... você está utilizando Typescript então?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addTourOverlay2() {

  // (1) 
  if (document.querySelectorAll('#tour-overlay').length === 0) {

    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = 'tour-overlay';
    let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

    // (2)
    newDiv.appendChild(body);

  }
  this.resizeOverlay();
}

resizeOverlay() {
  let window_height = screen.height;
  let window_width = screen.width;

  // (3 e 4)
  document.getElementById('#tour-overlay').style.height = window_height;
  document.getElementById('#tour-overlay').style.width = window_width;

}
```

Começando com algumas falhas triviais:

1. Se buscará pelo id é esperado que seja retornado apenas um elemento, [não vários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318255/5878); então ao invés de `querySelecorAll`, pode utilizar `querySelector` apenas (ou o `getElementById`);
2. Você adicionou `body` em `newDiv`; acredito que o correto seria `newDiv` em `body`;
3. Quando utilizar `getElementById` você não precisa informar o caractere `#`, apenas o valor do atributo;
4. Vide 3;

Sobre o erro

> O tipo 'number' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo 'string'. (linhas 36 e 37)

Isso vem do Typescript, que leva em consideração os tipos dos dados. Nesse caso, `screen.height` é um valor numérico, mas `element.style.height` é uma *string*. O que você precisa fazer é declarar o *cast* entre os tipos:

```
document.getElementById('#tour-overlay').style.height = <string> window_height; 
document.getElementById('#tour-overlay').style.width = <string> window_width;
// Aqui você informa o cast da variável ----------------^
```

Comment: Ao corrigir para **if ( document.getElementById('tour-overlay').length === 0)** recebi o seguinte erro: A propriedade 'length' não existe no tipo 'HTMLElement'.

Comment: Sim, pelo fato de não estar buscando uma lista, só um elemento. Precisará verificar se o retorno não é undefined

Comment: Em relação ao Cast da variável, ao ser corrigido o erro mudou para **O tipo 'number' não pode ser convertido para o tipo 'string'.**

Comment: O objetivo original era adicionar uma div do tamanho da tela do usuário, porém não posso usar jquery