# Como usar o Jquery.mask para CPF com input usando []

Tags: jquery, mask

Estou tentando usar o Jquery.mask para inserir uma máscara a um campo com CPF mas ele não funciona quando o campo tem o seguinte formato:

> $("#CPFPessoa[]")

O input está assim:

```
<input type="text" id="CPFPessoa[]" name="CPFPessoa[]" size="15" class="form-control">
```

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var $seuCampoCpf = $("#CPFPessoa[]");
        $seuCampoCpf.mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
    });
```

Preciso que o campo tenha esse formato pois estou usando um formulário que pode ser adicionado campos extras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você só usa colchetes `[]` no `name`, não no `id`.

Mas não use id já que vai poder repetir o campo ([veja esta pergunta sobre repetição de id's](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318255/8063)). Pode usar como seletor o atributo `name`:

```
var $seuCampoCpf = $("[name='CPFPessoa[]']");
```

Ou trocar o `id` por `class`:

```
<input type="text" class="CPFPessoa" name="CPFPessoa[]" size="15" class="form-control">
```

E o seletor:

```
var $seuCampoCpf = $(".CPFPessoa");
```

Comment: Valeu @Sam, muito obrigado pela excelente dica.