# É errado criar checkboxes com o name igual?

Tags: html

Criar varias `checkbox` com o mesmo name pode ser considerado errado? 
Visto que o `value` é o que define o `dado` da `checkbox`.
Ou realmente devo ter `names` diferentes?

```
<tr>
  <td>Status</td>
  <td colspan="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="single" id="chk_stat">single

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="married" id="chk_stat">Married

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="divorcee" id="chk_stat">Divorcee

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="student" id="chk_stat">Student
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Errado é colocar o mesmo id em todos os elementos.

Comment: Desta forma não, o que esta errado é a repetição de IDs, IDs devem ser unicos ([Por que é considerado errado/ruim repetir uma ID em HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318255/3635)). A forma dos names está OK, eles serão tratados com um vetor ao ser recebido no back-end.

Comment: Supondo que o name fosse apenas name="chk_stat" deixaria de ser correto?

Comment: Aí vai retornar sempre o último marcado. Seria incorreto para checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o mesmo `name` só faz sentido mesmo usar como array (adicionando `[]` ao `name`, como está fazendo). Ao contrário do `radio`, geralmente cada `checkbox` possui um `name` único, mas não há problemas em usar dessa forma.

> O incorreto é usar o mesmo `name` sem os colchetes, pois o back-end
>   irá receber apenas o último `checkbox` marcado.

O único possível problema, talvez, é que, se você marcar apenas o último, por exemplo, a array recebida no back-end sempre começará do índice `[0]`, ou seja:

```
Array ( [0] => student )
```

Answer (score 0):

Está correto.

Evite apenas repetir o ID pois eles devem ser únicos.

no PHP você poderá recuperá-los com `foreach`

```
foreach($_POST['chk_stat'] as key){
   //tratamento para cada combo selecionado
}
```