# Select com múltiplos valores JS

Tags: javascript

preciso muito da ajuda de vocês. Eu fiz um select em JS e funciona corretamente, o problema é que ele seleciona apenas um conteúdo e o que eu preciso é que ao selecionar o filtro de uma opção ele exiba todos os conteúdos relacionados.

Segue abaixo o código que eu fiz, apenas para mostrar a minha ideia.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.form-control').change(function(){
        $('.blocos').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

```css
<style type="text/css">

    .blocos {
        display: none;
    }

    .grupos {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around
    }

    #grupo-azul {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blue
    }

    #grupo-verde {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: green
    }

    #grupo-amarelo {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: yellow
    }

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Selecione a unidade</label><br>
    <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
        <option name="grupo-azul" value="grupo-azul">Todos os azuis</option>
        <option name="grupo-verde" value="grupo-verde">Todos os verdes</option>
        <option name="grupo-amarelo" value="grupo-amarelo">Todos os Amarelos</option>
    
    </select>
</div>

<div class="grupos">
    <div id="grupo-azul" class="blocos"></div>
    <div id="grupo-verde" class="blocos"></div>
    <div id="grupo-amarelo" class="blocos"></div>
    <div id="grupo-azul" class="blocos"></div>
    <div id="grupo-amarelo" class="blocos"></div>
    <div id="grupo-verde" class="blocos"></div>
</div>
```

Por gentileza, conseguem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O id de um elemento é um **identificador único** ([melhores explicações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318255/por-que-%C3%A9-considerado-errado-ruim-repetir-uma-id-em-html/318309#318309)) e você colocou vários elementos com o mesmo id, dessa forma o seu script irá procurar o primeiro elemento com aquele id informado e aplicar as ações nele, por isso a ação é executada em apenas um elemento. Nessa situação eu recomendo mudar o seletor para classe

```
<div class="grupos">
    <div class="blocos grupo-azu"></div>
    <div class="blocos grupo-verde"></div>
    <div class="blocos grupo-amarelo"></div>
    <div class="blocos grupo-azul"></div>
    <div class="blocos grupo-amarelo"></div>
    <div class="blocos grupo-verde"></div>
</div>
```

E em seu `script` alterar o seletor de `#` para `.`, para que assim possa ser referenciado a `classe` e não o `id`

```
$('.' + $(this).val()).show();

.grupo-azul {}
```

Com as correções aplicadas:

```js
 
 $(function() {
        $('.form-control').change(function(){
           $('.blocos').hide();
            $('.' + $(this).val()).show();

        });
    });
```

```css
<style type="text/css">

    .blocos {
        display: none;
    }

    .grupos {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around
    }

    .grupo-azul {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blue
    }

    .grupo-verde {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: green
    }

    .grupo-amarelo {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: yellow
    }

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Selecione a unidade</label><br>
    <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
        <option name="grupo-azul" value="grupo-azul">Todos os azuis</option>
        <option name="grupo-verde" value="grupo-verde">Todos os verdes</option>
        <option name="grupo-amarelo" value="grupo-amarelo">Todos os Amarelos</option>
  
    </select>
</div>

<div class="grupos">
    <div class="blocos grupo-azu"></div>
    <div class="blocos grupo-verde"></div>
    <div class="blocos grupo-amarelo"></div>
    <div class="blocos grupo-azul"></div>
    <div class="blocos grupo-amarelo"></div>
    <div class="blocos grupo-verde"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela explicação, me ajudou muito. Vlw