# Não consigo pegar o valor da coluna ao lado do meu input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um problema que não sei o motivo...
Tenho uma tabela no qual uma das colunas fica o input e quando onkeyup neste input, eu preciso pegar o innerHTML da coluna ao lado:
[image: printscreen]

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#pedido').on('keyup', '.qte', function () {
    var x = $(this).closest('#custo').innerHTML;
       console.log(x)
  });
  </script>
```

Ele não está achando o #custo, volta a mensagem de undefined.

O que será que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Se `#custo` é um id, então ele é único na página, então não basta fazer `$("#custo")`?

Comment: Anderson, ele não é o único. Pode ter mais de uma linha. É uma tabela de pedido.

Comment: Então a estrutura do seu HTML está errada. [Por que é considerado errado/ruim repetir uma ID em HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318255/5878)

Comment: Você está correto, eu deveria usar então a classe. Porém mesmo assim não funciona...

Comment: Então edite a pergunta e adicione um [mcve] que reproduza o problema

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado pelo seu tempo... Se não conseguiu entender meu problema, não é você quem vai me ajudar.

Comment: Jeferson, recomendo que faça o [tour], leia o guia de [ask] e acesse a [help] para mais informações sobre o funcionamento do site. Isso te ajudará bastante nas interações futuras. Não é uma questão de entender o problema, isso ficou claro, só não há como reproduzí-lo para sugerirmos a solução. Veja que mesmo na resposta no Virgilio Novic bem no final ele diz exatamente isso. A única coisa nessa situação é mostrar uma forma de fazer, correndo o risco de não ser válido para você e mesmo se funcionar você ficará sem entender porquê o seu não funcionou. Não vejo vantagens para ninguém nisso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a sua duvida é simples e fiz um exemplo minimo:

```js
function changeValue(e, value, obj) {
  document.getElementById(e).textContent = (value * obj.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>1700,00</td>
 <td>
  <input type="number" onKeyUp="changeValue('s1', 1700, this)" />
 </td>
 <td><span id="s1">0</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>2.000,00</td>
 <td>
  <input type="number" onKeyUp="changeValue('s2', 2000, this)" />
 </td>
 <td><span id="s2">0</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Eu não tenho como refletir o seu exemplo, faltou a sua tabela criada para que eu possa entender como você fez a sua, isso é um norte, um caminho que pode ser seguido com as devidas alterações ([protótipo](https://www.significados.com.br/prototipo/)).

Comment: Muito obrigado, era bem isso mesmo! Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Jefferson, um id não pode ser repetido. Troque o id `#custo` por uma `class="custo"`. E o `.closest()` não irá buscar um elemento "ao lado", ele busca um elemento pai mais próximo. E não use `.innerHTML` com objetos jQuery, use `.text()`, que irá retornar o texto do elemento. Em adicional, use `.trim()` para remover os espaços que o HTML gera ao indentar o texto dentro da célula.

Ficaria assim:

```
var x = $(this).closest('tr').find(".custo").text().trim();
```

O `.closest("tr")` irá buscar a linha do input e buscar a célula com a classe `.custo` e retornar o texto contido nela.