# personalizar o serviço a ser prestado (ex.: informar a quantidade de horas de aula-particular que deseja contratar)

Tags: javascript, html5

Nesse exercício quero criar um sistema em **JavaScript** que personalize uma solicitação de um serviço, nesse caso aulas particulares de JS. A minha intenção foi mostrar ao usuário uma div que apresentava um novo form quando quisesse selecionar o pagamento por aula, esse form pede a quantidade de horas e quantidade de dias na semana que o aluno iria solicitar aulas de Java Script. Pra isso criei uma função **formqtd** que eu acho que funciona. Porém no momento do click do botão  enviar, a resposta dizendo o preço do serviço não aparece, da mesma forma para o pagamento mensal.

**SCRIPT**
        ```Java script

````
        function formqtd()
        {
            if(document.getElementById("aulaCheck").checked)
            {
                document.getElementById("formqtd").style.display="block";
                document.getElementById("botao2").style.display="block";
                document.getElementById("botao1").style.display="none";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("mesCheck").checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById("formqtd").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("botao2").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("botao1").style.display="block";
            }
        }

        function aulaP(){



            let pagaula = document.getElementById("aulaCheck").value;
            let pagmes = document.getElementById("mesCheck").value;
            let qtdhora = Number(document.getElementById("hora").value);
            let qtddias = Number(document.getElementById("dias").value);
            let resposta = "";

            if(pagaula.checked)
            {
                let pagaula = 30;
                let precoaula = (pagaula * qtdhora);
                let pagfinal = precoaula * qtddias;

                document.getElementById("aulaP()").innerHTML  = ("O plano aula é" + pagaula + " por hora. Já que você precisará de " + qtdhora + " horas por aula, durante " + qtddias + " na semana, o preço final é: " + pagfinal.toFixed(2));
            }
            else if (pagmes.checked)
            {
                let pagmes = 280;
                let pagfinal = pagmes;

                resposta = ("O pagamento final do plano mensal é:" + pagfinal.toFixed(2));
            }
            let respostafinal = resposta;
            document.getElementById("aulaP()").innerHTML = respostafinal;
        }

    ```
````

**HTML**

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div class="conteudo">
                <h1>Aulas Particulares</h1><br>
                <h2>Aulas JS</h2>
                <h3> R$30 a hora/aula ou plano mensal R$280 </h3>
                <form>
                    <label> Selecione seu plano: </label><br>
                    <label for="aulaCheck">R$30 hora</label>
                        <input type="radio" onclick="formqtd(); aulaP();" name="plano" id="aulaCheck"><br>
                    <label for="mesCheck"> Plano Mensal 2 aulas/semana R$280</label>
                        <input type="radio" onclick="formqtd(); aulaP();" name="plano" id="mesCheck">

<button type="button" id="botao1" onclick="aulaP()">Enviar</button>
                </form><br> 

                    <h3>Resposta</h3>
                    <p id="aulaP()"></p>

            </div>

            <div class="conteudo" id="formqtd" style="display: none;">
                <form>
                    <h3>Horas e dias da semana</h3>
                        <label for="hora">Hora:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="hora"><br>
                        <label> Quantos dias na semana? (n°)</label>
                            <input type="text" id="dias">

                            <button type="button" onclick="formqtd(); aulaP();" id="botao2"><b>Enviar</b></button>
                </form>
                        <h3>Resposta</h3>
                        <p id="aulaP()"></p>
            </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

**desculpe a formatação** ainda não sei usar o stackoverflow propriamente.

Answer (score 0):

Muitos problemas no código. Não use `()` nos id's. Não repita um elemento com o mesmo id — um id deve ser [único numa página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318255/8063).

Chame apenas a função `formqtd()` nos radios e a função `aulaP()` nos botões <kbd>Enviar</kbd>.

O `<p id="aulaP"></p>`, que você está repetindo com o mesmo id, basta colocá-lo apenas 1 vez após as duas divs, e esvazie ela ao chamar a função `formqtd()` com `document.getElementById("aulaP").innerHTML = '';`.

Na função `aulaP()`, onde você quer saber qual radio foi checado, não pegue o `value` dos elementos. Para saber se está checado, pegue apenas os elementos, ou seja, em vez de:

```
let pagaula = document.getElementById("aulaCheck").value;
let pagmes = document.getElementById("mesCheck").value;
```

Seria:

```
let pagaula = document.getElementById("aulaCheck");
let pagmes = document.getElementById("mesCheck");
```

E onde tem:

```
document.getElementById("aulaP()").innerHTML  = ("O plano aula é" + pagaula + " por hora. Já que você precisará de " + qtdhora + " horas por aula, durante " + qtddias + " na semana, o preço final é: " + pagfinal.toFixed(2));
```

Seria o valor da variável `resposta` que será inserida na div ao final da função:

```
resposta  = "O plano aula é" + pagaula + " por hora. Já que você precisará de " + qtdhora + " horas por aula, durante " + qtddias + " na semana, o preço final é: " + pagfinal.toFixed(2);
```

E não precisa colocar entre `()` a string da variável.

Ficará assim tudo:

```js
function formqtd()
{
  
  document.getElementById("aulaP").innerHTML = '';
   if(document.getElementById("aulaCheck").checked)
   {
       document.getElementById("formqtd").style.display="block";
       document.getElementById("botao2").style.display="block";
       document.getElementById("botao1").style.display="none";
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("mesCheck").checked) 
   {
       document.getElementById("formqtd").style.display="none";
       document.getElementById("botao2").style.display="none";
       document.getElementById("botao1").style.display="block";
   }
}

function aulaP(){



   let pagaula = document.getElementById("aulaCheck");
   let pagmes = document.getElementById("mesCheck");
   let qtdhora = Number(document.getElementById("hora").value);
   let qtddias = Number(document.getElementById("dias").value);
   let resposta = "";

   if(pagaula.checked)
   {
       let pagaula = 30;
       let precoaula = (pagaula * qtdhora);
       let pagfinal = precoaula * qtddias;

       resposta  = "O plano aula é" + pagaula + " por hora. Já que você precisará de " + qtdhora + " horas por aula, durante " + qtddias + " na semana, o preço final é: " + pagfinal.toFixed(2);
   }
   else if (pagmes.checked)
   {
       let pagmes = 280;
       let pagfinal = pagmes;

       resposta = "O pagamento final do plano mensal é:" + pagfinal.toFixed(2);
   }
   let respostafinal = resposta;
   document.getElementById("aulaP").innerHTML = respostafinal;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
    <h1>Aulas Particulares</h1><br>
    <h2>Aulas JS</h2>
    <h3> R$30 a hora/aula ou plano mensal R$280 </h3>
    <form>
        <label> Selecione seu plano: </label><br>
        <label for="aulaCheck">R$30 hora</label>
            <input type="radio" onclick="formqtd();" name="plano" id="aulaCheck"><br>
        <label for="mesCheck"> Plano Mensal 2 aulas/semana R$280</label>
            <input type="radio" onclick="formqtd();" name="plano" id="mesCheck">

<button type="button" id="botao1" onclick="aulaP()">Enviar</button>
    </form><br> 

        <h3>Resposta</h3>

</div>

<div class="conteudo" id="formqtd" style="display: none;">
    <form>
        <h3>Horas e dias da semana</h3>
            <label for="hora">Hora:</label>
                <input type="text" id="hora"><br>
            <label> Quantos dias na semana? (n°)</label>
                <input type="text" id="dias">

                <button type="button" onclick="aulaP();" id="botao2"><b>Enviar</b></button>
    </form>
            <h3>Resposta</h3>
</div>
<p id="aulaP"></p>
```