# Erro JavaScript [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, html, html5

**Não sei o que fazer para ter o resultado correto com esse código. Pois sempre que eu mando conferir ele me retorna esse resultado.**

Eu tentei fazer o uso do `document.querySelector`. Mas o erro [object HTMLDivElement] permanece.
Eu precisava que onde está `` res.innerHTML = `Você nasceu em ${pais}` `` Fosse substituído  pelas string que eu colocasse dentro dos inputs.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

````
        <h1>Validação de País</h1>
        <div id="nome">
            Digite seu nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
        </div>
        <div id="pais">
            Digite seu pais:&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais">
        </div>
        <div id="button">
             <input type="button" value="Conferir" onclick="conferir()">

        </div>
        <div id="res">Resultado:</div>
    </main>

    <script>

        function conferir(){
            var pais = document.getElementById('pais')
            //var pais = document.querySelector('div#pais')
            var nome = document.getElementById('nome')
            var res = document.getElementById('res')

            res.innerHTML = `Você nasceu em ${pais}`
        }


    </script> ```
````

Answer (score 2):

São dois **erros de digitação** seus

O método `var pais = document.getElementById('pais')` pega o elemento e não o valor injetado no elemento

E NUNCA repita IDs, como dito em [Por que é considerado errado/ruim repetir uma ID em HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318255/3635), você repetiu aqui:

```
<div id="pais">
    Digite seu pais:&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais">
```

E em outros lugares

Mude para:

```
<div id="nome">
    Digite seu nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="nomeField">
</div>
<div id="pais">
    Digite seu pais:&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="paisField" id="pais">
</div>
<div id="button">
     <input type="button" value="Conferir" onclick="conferir()">

</div>
```

O campos nomeField e paisField são apenas exemplos, você pode optar por outros nomes, desde que nunca repita os IDs.

E pra pegar o valor deve usar a propriedade `.value`, assim:

```
var pais = document.getElementById('paisField')
var nome = document.getElementById('nomeField')
var res = document.getElementById('res')

res.innerHTML = `Você nasceu em ${pais.value}`
```

Ou assim:

```
var pais = document.getElementById('paisField').value //.value aqui

var nome = document.getElementById('nomeField')
var res = document.getElementById('res')

res.innerHTML = `Você nasceu em ${pais}`
```