# Dúvida sobre atribuição de classes e ids

Tags: html

Existe alguma boa prática que orienta a ordem que devo definir o `id` e a `class` de um elemento HTML? Sei que tanto faz a ordem para o navegador renderizar, mas existe algum guia de estilo de código para isso?

Comment: Isso deve responder, se não, acho que tem outras no site que responde, várias vezes o assunto foi tratado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39875/101. Veja também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117922/101

Comment: Obrigado, @Maniero.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a prioridade do HTML? "id" ou "class"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39875/qual-a-prioridade-do-html-id-ou-class)

Comment: @Sorack Acho que não seja duplicata. Esta refere-se à ordem para se colocar os atributos no elementos, enquanto a que citou refere-se à ordem de prioridade que são aplicados os estilos. Está fortemente relacionada, mas acho que não chega a ser duplicata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a documentação que está nesse **Guia de Boas Práticas da Mozilla**, o `ID` deve vir depois da `class`:

> As `classes` são ótimos componentes reutilizáveis, então elas vêm em primeiro lugar. Os `ID`s são mais específicos e devem ser usados ​​com moderação (por exemplo, para bookmarks in-page), então eles vêm em segundo lugar.

```
<a class="..." id="..." data-toggle="modal" href="#">
    Example link
</a>
```

***Fonte:*** https://codeguide.co/#css-shorthand

Então, basicamente a Mozilla diz que como o ID é mais específico ele deve vir por último. Mas isso não é regra, é uma recomendação deles.

Já o **Bootstrap** por exemplo, que é um *Framewrok* gigante e super popular parece não ter um padão, algo estranho ao meu ver... Para eles o `ID` vem primeiro em alguns componentes, e depois em outros...

Por exemplo, repare que nas tags iniciais do Carroussel o `ID` vem primeiro, enquanto que na tag do Modal a `Classe` é que vem primeiro, e os dois são componentes do mesmo *Framework*.

Tag inicial do Carrossel https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/carousel/:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

Tag inicial do Modal https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/modal/:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalExemplo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Eu não considero isso uma boa prática, o ideal seria adotar alguma regra para facilitar a manutenção e leitura do código.

---

**Recomendação da Google:** *Não há recomendação* :)

No ***Guia de Estilos da Google*** esse assunto de ordem dos atributos na tag nem é mencionado... https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html

Comment: Obrigado, @hugocsl. Vou passar a colocar minhas classes primeiro, também acho que facilita a leitura do código ter um padrão. Estranho o Bootstrap não ter...

Comment: @ThiagoKrempser estranho mesmo o BS não seguir um padrão... eu fui lá justamente para ver o padrão que eles seguiam haha, mas logo percebi que parece não ter padrão... Eu meu ver em um FW tão grade deveria haver uma regra pra esse tipo de coisa...

Answer (score 0):

No cenário do CSS, eu te recomendo fazer uso da **class** quando possível, já que são reutilizáveis, e fazer uso do ID com moderação, visto que são únicos e não podem ser reutilizados, perdendo muito dos benefícios de reutilização do CSS em múltiplos locais.

Também quando você começa a utilizar seletores com **ID**, você está automaticamente limitando aquele estilo a um único elemento.

Seja cauteloso ao utilizar IDs, validar de fato será necessário. Quando falamos sobre manipulação dos elementos do DOM, o ID de fato é melhor recomendado. Caso você vá utilizar, faça-o apenas em tags específicas e únicas do seu sistema para evitar conflitos.

Segue link para você conferir a especificação do Mozilla sobre selectores por classe ou ID: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Getting_Started/Seletores

Manipulação do ID em js: (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp)

Comment: Mas ninguém falou em seletores. A recomendação de não utilizar ID para seletor até faz certo sentido, mas não neste contexto. Neste, para falar a verdade, ficou uma recomendação inválida, pois o ID tem sua função (importante) no DOM e deve ser avaliada dentro da necessidade e contexto adequados.

Comment: Ajustei minha resposta meu amigo. observei apenas o cenário comum do meu dia dia. Concordo quando a manipulação do elemento do DOM. Abraços.