# Qual seletor CSS tem prioridade?

Tags: html, css, css3, seletores

Tenho o seguinte código `HTML` e `CSS`:

```css
#element    p{color:blue;}
.element    p{color:red;}
div         p{color:pink;}
div.element p{color:yellow;}
div[name="element"] p{color:purple;}
div p:first-child{color:brown;}
div p:nth-child(1){color:white;}
```

```html
<div class="element" id="element" name="element">
     <p>Elemento</p>
</div>
```

Sei que já há uma [pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39875/qual-a-prioridade-do-html-id-ou-class), mas nesse caso estou tratando com uma série de seletores, e não somente `classe` e `id`.

- Porque é aplicado o estilo do seletor `id` ?
- Porque o `id` tem prioridade em cima dos outros **tantos** seletores, já que os demais vem depois dele ?
- Na última linha de estilo eu tenho um caminho com **3 seletores** e mesmo assim o `id` tem prioridade, porquê ?

Comment: Fiquei encucado por que `div p` não deu ficou `pink`. Mas boa parte dessa questão tem respondida aqui [Qual a prioridade do HTML? “id” ou “class”?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39875/qual-a-prioridade-do-html-id-ou-class).

Comment: Eu entendo sobre as precedências, porém na teoria o caminho mais específico deveria ganhar.

Comment: `#element p` é mais específico do que uma div qualquer seguida de p, por isso prevalece o blue ao pink.

Comment: Concordo com você @Bacco, mas nos demais tenho até 3 seletores isso não seria mais específico ?

Comment: @RicardoMota acrescentei explicações na resposta, e uma ferramenta que você talvez vá achar interessante :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Basicamente, a regra seguida é a da "especificidade":

> https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

A especificidade é calculada da seguinte forma:

- O seletor universal `*` é ignorado.
- `a` = número de IDs em cada seletor;
- `b` = número de seletores de classes, atributos e pseudoclasses;
- `c` = número de seletores de tipo e pseudoelementos;
- estilos inline (`style=""`) tem mais prioridade que as 3 condições acima.

Usando os valores a-b-c você obtém o índice de classificação (vale o maior):

```css
  ┌── maior especificidade   
┌─┴─┐
1-0-3 > 0-14-5 > 0-2-1 > 0-0-12 
                         └─┬──┘
    menor especificidade ──┘
```

Quando os índices forem iguais, prevalece o último definido no CSS, respeitando a "cascata".

Exemplos:

```css
*               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> especificidade =       0 */
LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> especificidade =       1 */
UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> especificidade =       2 */
UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> especificidade =       3 */
H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> especificidade =     1-1 */
UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> especificidade =     1-3 */
LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> especificidade =     2-1 */
#x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> especificidade =   1-0-0 */
#s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> especificidade =   1-0-1 */
style="..."     /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> especificidade = 1-0-0-0 */
```

#### Notas:

- Se ocorrer repetição do mesmo seletor simples, a especificidade também aumenta (cada ocorrência é contabilizada).
- a declaração dentro de `style=""` é considerada como `1-0-0-0` para fins de cálculo, sendo mais específica que o CSS do `id` do elemento, por exemplo.
- usar `!important` após uma definição tem prioridade sobre todas as outras declarações (caso tenha mais de um `!important`, o critério de desempate segue as regras já mencionadas)
- se o `!important` for aplicado num atalho como `background:`, vale como se tivesse sido aplicado em todos os sub-ítens do atalho (`background-color`, `background-position` etc)

Aplicado ao seu caso:

```css
#element    p{color:blue;}                /* 1-0-1 */
.element    p{color:red;}                 /*   1-1 */
div         p{color:pink;}                /*     2 */
div.element p{color:yellow;}              /*   1-2 */
div[name="element"] p{color:purple;}      /*   1-2 */
div p:first-child{color:brown;}           /*   1-2 */
div p:nth-child(1){color:white;}          /*   1-2 */
```

#### Ferramenta para cálculo online:

> http://specificity.keegan.st/

Veja também:

> [Qual a prioridade do HTML? "id" ou "class"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39875/70)

Comment: Agora ficou claro Bacco. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Não sabia que era feito um calculo. Muito bom saber disso.

Comment: Meus parabéns, uma das melhores explicações que li :D +1

Comment: +1 Muito bem explicado!