# Hover CSS afetar outro elemento

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte trecho de codigo

```
<td class="aluno" style="text-transform:uppercase">
  Fulano
  <a class="obs-aluno" href="#modal-obs" style="display:none">
   Link
  </a>
</td>
```

Quero que quando passe o mouse na TD o link que esta como display none se mostre. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com CSS:
Primeiro , tire o style da tag `<a>` e coloque na classe css. 
https://jsfiddle.net/1buoeckz/

```
.obs-aluno{
  display:none
}
.aluno:hover > a{
  display:block
}
```

Comment: Só salientando que o valor padrão de `display` do elemento `a` é `inline`, não `block`, então ao utilizar `block` nesta interação pode surgir efeitos indesejados.

Comment: boa observação! @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 4):

Com CSS é possível sim, porém você precisará remover a estilização *inline* do elemento, isso porquê o estilo definido no atributo `style` possui maior prioridade que estilos definidos no CSS, sendo impossível você sobrescrevê-los (sem utilizar o `!important`).

```css
a.obs-aluno {
  display: none;
}

td.aluno:hover > a.obs-aluno {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="aluno" style="text-transform:uppercase">
      Fulano
      <a class="obs-aluno" href="#modal-obs">Link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Utilizando o `!important` é possível, mas seu uso deve ser evitado, pois pode trazer problemas de depuração no futuro.

```css
td.aluno:hover > a.obs-aluno {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="aluno" style="text-transform:uppercase">
      Fulano
      <a class="obs-aluno" href="#modal-obs" style="display: none">Link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

É importante salientar a ordem de prioridade dos estilos:

1. Estilos *inline*, definidos em `style`;
2. Estilos no CSS definidos com o id;
3. Estilos no CSS definidos com a classe;
4. Estilos no CSS definidos para o elemento;

Veja os exemplos abaixo:

1. Com todos os estilos aplicados ao mesmo elementos, será priorizado o estilo `inline`.

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

#green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" style="color: red" class="yellow" id="green">Link</a>
```

2. Com os estilos de id, classe e elemento aplicados, será priorizado o id.

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

#green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="yellow" id="green">Link</a>
```

3. Com os estilos de classe e elemento aplicados, será priorizado a classe.

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

#green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="yellow">Link</a>
```

4. O estilo do elemento somente é aplicado quando nenhum outro estiver presente.

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

#green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

**Leitura adicional**

[Qual seletor css tem prioridade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143850/5878)

Answer (score 1):

Com o script abaixo ao passar o mouse o link será mostrado e ao retirar o mouse, o link será ocultado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nome").mouseover(function(){
        $(".obs-aluno").css("display", "block");
    });
    $("#nome").mouseout(function(){
        $(".obs-aluno").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td class="aluno" style="text-transform:uppercase">
  <p id="nome">Fulano</p>
  <a class="obs-aluno" href="#modal-obs" style="display:none">
   Link
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Excelente, porem com CSS puro é possivel? Se for essa resposta me serviu bem!

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo apenas com CSS.

```css
a{
  display:none;
}

div:hover a{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Fulano
  <a href="#">LINK</a>
</div>
```