# A propriedade "!important" do CSS influencia no desempenho do site?

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber se ao atribuir a propriedade `!important` influencia no desempenho do site, pois eu o utilizo bastante para sobrepor o **bootstrap** por exemplo.

Comment: **Não** muito, nem mesmo seletores complexos irão influenciar tanto, existem pessoas que vão afirmar que influencia, mas isto se chama micro-otimização, que nada mais que é questão de micro-segundos. Existem libs Js e uma série de plugins que são os verdadeiros fatores da causa da demora, muitos pseudo-entendidos de front-end usam uma série de libs quase que aleatoriamente sem saber o que estão prejudicando a performance.

Comment: No desempenho nem tanto, vide comentário acima, mas na manutenção do projeto influencia muito. Hoje você pode saber o que está fazendo, mas daqui um tempo, se precisar alterar algo no projeto em produção, até você lembrar que utilizou um `!important` pode demorar tempo desnecessário, pois poderá haver múltiplos seletores que definem a cor da fonte do seu elemento como vermelho, mas aparece verde. Estresse desnecessário. Eu particularmente evito sempre utilizá-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não deve ter qualquer efeito sobre o desempenho realmente. Vendo o analisador de CSS do Firefox em [/source/layout/style/nsCSSDataBlock.cpp#572](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla2.0/source/layout/style/nsCSSDataBlock.cpp#572) acho que essa é a rotina relevante, tratando de substituir essa regra do CSS.

Parece ser uma simples rotina para checar se é "importante".

```
 if (aIsImportant) {
    if (!HasImportantBit(aPropID))
      changed = PR_TRUE;
    SetImportantBit(aPropID);
  } else {
    // ...
```

Além disso tem comentários em [source/layout/style/nsCSSDataBlock.h#219](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla2.0/source/layout/style/nsCSSDataBlock.cpp#219)

```
/**
 * Transfer the state for |aPropID| (which may be a shorthand)
 * from |aFromBlock| to this block.  The property being transferred
 * is !important if |aIsImportant| is true, and should replace an
 * existing !important property regardless of its own importance
 * if |aOverrideImportant| is true.
 * 
 * ...
 */
```

> 1. O Firefox usa um analisador de baixo para cima escrito manualmente. Em ambos os casos, cada arquivo CSS é analisado em um objeto StyleSheet, cada objeto contém regras CSS.
> 2. O Firefox cria árvores de contexto de estilo que contêm os valores finais (depois de aplicar todas as regras na ordem correta)

[image]

Agora, você pode ver facilmente, como, por exemplo, com o Modelo de Objeto descrito acima, o analisador pode marcar as regras afetadas pelo `!important` facilmente, sem muito custo. A degradação do desempenho não é um bom argumento contra `!important`.

No entanto, a manutenção é um golpe (como outras respostas mencionadas), que pode ser o seu único argumento contra elas.

> **Nota:** Tentei fazer a tradução contéudo original do StackOverflow em Inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743671/is-important-bad-for-performance

Answer (score 0):

É possível que sim, visto que o seu site irá carregar o CSS, e quanto estiver lendo ele (vai ler regras a mais) que estão sendo sobrepostas por outras das quais você utiliza o !important.

Pense que CSS é em cascata, ou seja se utiliza o !important, possivelmente está fazendo algo "errado"!

Leia esses artigos, que talvez ajude a entender melhor os problemas que pode ter ao utilizá-lo:

- https://zenorocha.com/css-important/
- https://j11y.io/css/dont-use-important/

Comment: Você tem certeza do que está falando? Isso não depende da renderização do _browser_? Sobre o segundo parágrafo: tem como embasar melhor?

Comment: O browser renderiza tudo conforme vai lendo do CSS...
Pense que o CSS trás a ideia de cascata, logo isso: https://jsfiddle.net/2tj21z9r/ é pior que isso: https://jsfiddle.net/2tj21z9r/1/

Comment: Cada navegador tem um próprio motor de renderização, baseado em uma estratégia própria para obter a melhor performance possível, talvez o `x { k: v !important;}` influenciaria em algo se a percepção humana fosse como a do Barry Allen, mas não, se usar alguns `!important` provavelmente não terá diferença alguma, se usar muitos mesmo talvez tenha uma pequena variação de algo como `0.00001` para `0.00003` segundos. Não tem como afirmar com precisão e desculpe, eu pessoalmente acho um baita erro afirmar qualquer coisa, como eu disse, cada navegador tem um motor próprio de renderização. ;)

Comment: Concordo que cada navegador tenha seu próprio motor de renderização e que cada vez mais eles estão a trabalhar para deixar tudo mais rápido. Todavia mesmo a pergunta não sendo essa, creio que devemos levar em consideração que isso é uma "bad practice" pois dificulta o debug e quebra a ideia de (cascata) natural do CSS, como sugere a documentação da MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Dificultar o Debug != Performance, fora que os depuradores como o do Chrome (e navegadores baseado em Chromium) e Safari por exemplo, são muito bons para fazer a analise do CSS. Pra falar realmente o que penso, mesmo achando o site MDN bom, ainda sim qualquer coisa que venha afirmar *"Boas (Más) praticas"* já é algo suspeito,  reio eu que eles não estão tão errados, é que isto é **muito relativo**, recomendo que **faça seus próprios testes** como um [benchmark](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computação)) até mais ;) ... Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143893/3635

Comment: O problema não é nem o debug, porque eu consigo me "encontrar" facilmente. É que meu CSS está crescendo (900 lines) e eu já usei muito !important por isso a preocupação.

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti faça o CSS sem `!important` se funcionar beleza, não precisa (muita coisa não precisa), se não conseguir "prioridade" então use `!important`, para resumir eu diria que a resposta é *"use `!important` se for necessário, se não for não use, independente da questão de performance"*

Comment: Em resumo, até onde se sabe o uso do *!important* não será nem perceptível no quesito _performance_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sim e não, claro que adicionar uma notação !important vai aumentar o tamanho do codigo, mas nada notavel, não hora da execução acredito que a diferença não seja perceptível, mas claro essa é uma resposta mais generica sobre o assunto, em grandes codigos pode ser que tenha uma minima diferença.