# Aplicando hover num article

Tags: css

Estou tentando aplicar um hover num article mas não está funcionando.

```
<style>

article.item{
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px #90ac6e solid; 
    border-radius: 6px; 
    background:#cfe8b1;
}

article.item:hover{
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px red solid; 
    border-radius: 6px; 
    background:#ffffff;
}

</style>

<article class="item" style="float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:15px; margin-bottom: 15px; width: 100px; height:100px; border: 1px #90ac6e solid; border-radius: 6px; background:#cfe8b1; text-align:center;">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:46pt; color:#666;"></i><br />
    <em style="font-family:padrao; size: 12pt; text-decoration:none; color:#003300;">Business Intelligence</em>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A razão porque isso não funciona é porque estilos aplicados inline, no HTML, têm mais peso que estilos no CSS. Dá uma olhada a esta [pergunta sobre isso em detalhe aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143850/129).

```css
article.item {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px #90ac6e solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #cfe8b1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .4s, border-color .4s;
  display: inline-block;
}

article.item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="content" style="float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top: 25px;  padding-left:5px; width:98%; border: 1px #90ac6e solid; border-radius: 6px; background:#f4ffe6; margin-bottom: 15px;">

<p style="margin:auto; padding: 35px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14pt; color:#003300; text-align:justify;">
<br />
O Kurma Suite BI foi especialmente desenvolvido pela Gopinatha&reg; para otimização da gestão das Concessionárias de Veículos. É a única Suite especializada na realidade das Concessionárias de Veículos do Brasil. Aqui você conta com as mais modernas técnicas de gestão, amplamente automatizadas, e de fácil compreensão.
<br />
</p>



<article class="item">
<a href="summary.php?id=724&fnc=<?php echo $prefix; ?>">
<i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-bottom: 0px; font-size:46pt; color:#666;"></i>
</a>

<a href="summary.php?id=724&fnc=<?php echo $prefix; ?>" style="font-family: padrao; text-decoration:none;">
<em style="font-family:padrao; size: 12pt; text-decoration:none; color:#003300;">Business Intelligence</em></a>
</article>

<article class="item">
<a href="premorc.php?id=730&fnc=<?php echo $prefix; ?>">
<i class="fa fa-pie-chart" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-bottom: 0px; font-size:46pt; color:#666;"></i>
<a href="premorc.php?id=730&fnc=<?php echo $prefix; ?>" style="font-family: padrao; text-decoration:none;"><em style="font-family:padrao; size: 12pt; text-decoration:none; color:#003300;">Budget</em></a>
</article>

<article class="item">
<i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:46pt; color:#ccc;"></i><br />
<em style="font-family:padrao; size: 12pt; text-decoration:none; color:#999;">Processos</em>
</article>

<article class="item">
<i class="fa fa-flag-checkered" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:46pt; color:#ccc;"></i><br />
<em style="font-family:padrao; size: 12pt; text-decoration:none; color:#999;">Planejamento Estratégico</em>
</article>

<article class="item">
<i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:46pt; color:#ccc;"></i><br />
<em style="font-family:padrao; size: 12pt; text-decoration:none; color:#999;">Gestão Matricial Despesas</em>
</article>


<article class="item">
<i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:46pt; color:#ccc;"></i><br />
<em style="font-family:padrao; size: 12pt; text-decoration:none; color:#999;">Treinamento</em>
</article>

<article class="item">
<i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:46pt; color:#ccc;"></i><br />
<em style="font-family:padrao; size: 12pt; text-decoration:none; color:#999;">Biblioteca Virtual</em>
</article>



</section>
```

Comment: Olá Sergio. Obrigado pela resposta. Parece que deu certo, mas agora, ao colocar sete articles como este lado a lado, eles aparecem verticalmente. Incluí um display: inline-block mas os articles aparecem desalinhados.

Comment: @WebsterMoitinho juntei mais 2 artigos no meu exemplo Não ficam assim para ti?

Comment: Ficou tudo desalinhado. O primeiro ficou certo, o segundo e o terceiro ficaram alinhados um com o outro, mas desalinhados com o primeiro, o quarto ficou alinhado com o primeiro, o quinto e o sexto alinhados com o segundo e terceiro, tá um rebu só kkkkk. Sou muito fraco de CSS...

Comment: @WebsterMoitinho eu não consigo ver o problema que estás a ter. Podes fazer um jsFiddle e colocar aqui?

Comment: Sergio, editei a sua resposta para exemplificar

Comment: @WebsterMoitinho ter `style` em todo esse HTML é um pesadelo. Tira isso e faz algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/cquvsf0e/

Comment: Obrigado Sergio. Agora deu certo. Valeu

Answer (score 2):

Para funcionar, você deve remover da *tag* *article* o atributo *style* e passar tudo que estava na *tag* para o *css*:

```
article.item{
    margin: 5px;
    float:left; 
    margin-left:10px; 
    margin-top:15px; 
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
    width: 100px; height:100px; 
    border: 1px #90ac6e solid; 
    border-radius: 6px; 
    background:#cfe8b1; 
    text-align:center;
}

article.item:hover{
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px red solid; 
    border-radius: 6px; 
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

Html:

```
<article class="item" style="">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:46pt; color:#666;"></i><br />
    <em style="font-family:padrao; size: 12pt; text-decoration:none; color:#003300;">Business Intelligence</em>
</article>
```

Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/06rsdt0z/

Mas se isso não for possível, você pode fazer uma "gambiara", colocando *important* na frente de tudo no hover:

```
article.item:hover{
    margin: 5px !important;
    border: 1px red solid !important; 
    border-radius: 6px !important; 
    background:#ffffff !important;
}
```

Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/06rsdt0z/1/

Comment: Olá Victor. Parece que deu certo, mas agora, ao colocar sete articles como este lado a lado, eles aparecem verticalmente. Incluí um display: inline-block mas os articles aparecem desalinhados.

Comment: Eles ficam desalinhados quando você passa o mouse por cima certo?

Comment: Não, ficam desalinhados mesmo

Comment: @WebsterMoitinho, faça outra pergunta sobre o inline-block, porque já foge  do escopo desta pergunta, a questão do hover já foi resolvida marque a reposta que achar melhor aqui, assim na outra pergunta vou poder responder com código e uma explicação melhor, o problema em especial desta pergunta foi a herança e já foi solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema está na aplicação do `style` diretamente na tag. Isso faz com que o `:hover` no `<style>` seja ignorado, pois declaração de estilo *inline* na tag tem mais importância (ou peso) do que o mesmo declarado no `<style></style>`.

No mais, é recomendado usar os estilos em *cascata* quando você tem múltiplos elementos com os mesmos estilos na página, tornando seu código mais enxuto e consequentemente mais fácil de manipular.

O código abaixo irá aplicar as regras de estilos aos elementos de uma só vez no CSS e fazer com seu `:hover` funcione corretamente:

```css
article.item{
margin: 5px;
  border: 1px #90ac6e solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #cfe8b1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .4s, border-color .4s;
  display: inline-block;
}

article em{
 font-family:padrao; size: 12pt; text-decoration:none; color:#003300;
}

article i{
 font-size:46pt; color:#666;
}

article.item:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<article class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"></i><br />
    <em>Business Intelligence</em>
</article>
<article class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"></i><br />
    <em>Business Intelligence</em>
</article>
<article class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"></i><br />
    <em>Business Intelligence</em>
</article>
<article class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"></i><br />
    <em>Business Intelligence</em>
</article>
<article class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"></i><br />
    <em>Business Intelligence</em>
</article>
<article class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"></i><br />
    <em>Business Intelligence</em>
</article>
<article class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"></i><br />
    <em>Business Intelligence</em>
</article>
```