# Jeito mais rápido de usar CSS

Tags: css

Qual o mais rápido de se usar:

```
.testando1{display: none;}
.testando2{display: none;}
.testando3{display: none;}
.testando4{display: none;}
.testando5{display: none;}
```

Ou:

```
.testando1, .testando2, .testando3, .testando4, .testando5 {display: none;}
```

Comment: Isso é de sua preferencia, mas eu simplesmente criaria uma `.hidden{display: none}` e aplicaria nas divs correspondentes.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto boa ideia! Mas eu por exemplo, em alguns clientes, não posso mexer totalmente no HTML do site, só em algumas páginas, e no CSS posso. Por isso estou na dúvida, em questão de performasse.

Comment: Use separando por virgula, quanto menos linha, mas leve o arquivo.

Comment: Para digitar o segundo, em questão de performance não é possivel afirmar, pode variar de motor para motor (motor é a tecnologia de cada navegador responsável por interpretar e renderizar), provavelmente para o interpretador a diferença seja de 0.0000002 segundos, algo que seria uma perda de tempo se preocupar com isto, o ideal é procurar pontos mais evidente para melhorar a performance, como usar HTTP-cache, minificar resources, carregar somente o que vai usar (quando possivel), isso tudo em produção apenas. O que recomendo se preocupar é com isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143850/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um arquivo CSS com apenas essas instruções abaixo pesa *75 bytes*:

```
.testando1, .testando2, .testando3, .testando4, .testando5 {display: none;}
```

Um outro arquivo com essas pesa *138 bytes*:

```
.testando1{display: none;}
.testando2{display: none;}
.testando3{display: none;}
.testando4{display: none;}
.testando5{display: none;}
```

> O tamanho dos arquivos podem variar dependendo do sistema de arquivos utilizado pelo SO ou da indentação utilizada.

Apesar de serem arquivos extremamente leves dá pra saber que a primeira opção é melhor em termo performance pois carregará mais rápido.

Mas como o [Rafael Augusto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/75515/rafael-augusto) falou, nessa situação seria melhor criar uma nova classe e adiciona-la nos elementos.