# Como corrijo css ou código do meu logo do site para ele manter sempre o tamanho original de largura e altura

Tags: css, wordpress

coloquei css adicional:

```
nav-brand-sitelogo {
    height: 91px!important;  
    width: 300px!important;
}

element.style {
  height: 91px!important;  
    width: 300px!important;
}

.can-shrink-brand.sticky-brand-shrink-on .desktop-sticky .navbar-brand img {
height: 91px!important;
width: 300px!important; 
 }
```

Mas na hora que publico não atualiza o logo ficar da mesma altura, na hora que desço com a barra de rolagem ele da uma distorcida

```
<img src="https://mdwebdesign.tk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/mdlogopng.png" alt="Voltar para a página inicial" class="" width="300" height="91" style="max-width:250px;max-height:100px" data-no-retina="" data-czr-model_id="logo" data-czr-template="templates/parts/header/parts/logo">
```

Acho que é este max witdh e max-heght, mas já defini tudo para 300 x 91 não sei como corrigir
Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema pode ser pq vc tem um classe com uma hierarquia maior definindo a altura máxima como 30px.

Outro ponto é que:

> As propriedades `min-height` e `max-height` sobrepõem a `height`.

Como vc pode ler nessa documentação da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/height

Ajuste seu CSS aqui:

```
.can-shrink-brand.sticky-brand-shrink-on .desktop-sticky .navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 30px!important; /* mude a altura aqui*/
    width: auto!important;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**DICA**: Vc pode ler sobre a hierarquia e prioridade de classes aqui nessa pergunta: [Qual seletor css tem prioridade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143850/qual-seletor-css-tem-prioridade)

Comment: Ok, Obrigado
Agora deu certo

Comment: @matheusdouradobr legal que deu certo ai! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da resposta se vc achar que ajudou a resolver o problema. Assim o site não fica com a sua pergunta em aberto pendente sem resposta aceita mesmo já tendo sido resolvida. []´s