# Hover em terceira div afetar a primeira - Elemento irmão anterior - Com CSS Puro

Tags: css, css-hover

```
<div class="selelikes-wrap">

<div class="selelike">
<span><</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>0</span>
</div>

<div class="seleunlike">

<span>></span>

</div>
```

Quero que a div de classe **seleunlike** ao passar o mouse mexa na **selelike**, e vice versa.

Quem puder ajudar fico muito grato!

http://jsfiddle.net/r0vdw1qm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha apesar de alguns falarem que é impossível, digo que em alguns casos como o seu é possível sim!

Mas para isso vc vai precisar de alguma maldade com CSS, pois vai precisar de regras meio complexas como:

```
.selelikes-wrap:hover div:nth-child(1):hover ~ div{...}
```

e

```
.selelikes-wrap:hover div:not(:hover):nth-child(1){...}
```

Essas regras precisam ser assim principalmente devido a `prioridade` e `hierarquia` na hora de aplicar o estilo, onde uma regra precisa ter a força maior que outra. Vc pode ler mais sobre isso aqui: [Qual seletor css tem prioridade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143850/qual-seletor-css-tem-prioridade)

Outro ponto MUITO importante é que o *container* pai precisa ser em `flex`, pois com o `flex` eu posso usar o atributo `order` para determinar qual vai ser a ordem que os filhos vão aparecer na tela, mesmo a ordem no `dom` sendo diferente.

Dessa forma a `div` com o `0` na verdade é a primeira no `dom`, mas na tela ela é a segunda classe `.txt`! De qq forma, sendo a primeira eu posso atingir os irmãos abaixo com o seletor `+` ou `~`.

Veja na imagem abaixo como ficou, a `div` com o `0` na verdade é o primeiro filho, mas na tela renderiza como segundo filho. Mas no `dom` e no css ele permanece como primeiro filho

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o código referente a imagem. Pode ser que seja possível refinar ainda mais esse CSS, mas hj acordei de ressaca e foi o melhor que consegui pensar :D

```css
.selelike,
.seleunlike {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    cursor: pointer
}

.selelikes-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}
.selelikes-wrap:hover div:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.selelikes-wrap:hover div:not(:hover){
    transform: scale(0.9);
    background-color: orange;
}
.selelikes-wrap:hover div:nth-child(1){
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: transparent;
}
.selelikes-wrap:hover div:nth-child(1):hover ~ div{
    background-color: transparent;
}
.selelikes-wrap:hover div:not(:hover):nth-child(1){
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.selelikes-wrap:hover .txt:hover + .selelike {
    transform: scale(1);
}
.selelikes-wrap:hover .txt:hover ~ .seleunlike {
    transform: scale(1);
}

/* repare que no dom o iv .txt é o primeiro filho,
mas usando a propriedade "order" eu renderizo na tela 
a div .txt visualmente como segundo filho :) */
.selelike {
    order: 1;
}
.txt {
    order: 2;
}
.seleunlike {
    order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="selelikes-wrap">

    <div class="txt">
        <span>0</span>
    </div>

    <div class="selelike">
        <span><</span> 
    </div> 

    <div class="seleunlike">
        <span>></span>
    </div>

</div>
```