# Mudar cor do link quando passar o mouse por cima no Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Comecei a aprender bootstrap hoje e fiz um site de teste bem simples. Nele tem um navbar com alguns links. A questão é que não consigo trocar a cor nos links ao passar o mouse de jeito nenhum, só fica com a interação padrão (escurecer ao passar o mouse). Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficaria grato, segue o código

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <!--Bootstrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!--Fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--Stylesheet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Teste</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div id="navbar" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Teste</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#indicadores">Indicadores</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#aprendizagem">Aprendizagem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#graficos">Gráficos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#simulador">Simulador</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#carteira">Carteira</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Registrar-se</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Entrar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <h3>Exemplo</h3>
            <p>Testando a página em Bootstrap</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
body {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    margin: 0px;
}

/*----------Navbar----------*/

.container-fluid a:hover{
    color: rgb(26, 244, 183);
}

#navbar {
    background-color: rgb(46,41,58);
    margin: 0px;
}

.navbar, .navbar-default {
    border: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: aqua;
}

.navbar-nav {
    color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: Temos uma solução para esta no Stackoverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625972/change-color-of-bootstrap-navbar-on-hover-link

Comment: Era só colocar a declaração **!important** no hover ficando assim: **`nav a:hover { color: aqua !important; }`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo estilo do CSS do Bootstrap, os links `<a>` da nav tem mais força, ou seja, tem maior especificidade ([veja como calcular a especificidade nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143893/8063)) do que quando você coloca `nav a{ color: aqua; }`. O Bootstrap define as propriedades dos links com o estilo abaixo:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #777;
}
```

Ou seja, o estilo acima tem mais força do que:

```
nav a{
   color: aqua;
}
```

E isso vale o mesmo para o `:hover`. Se você deseja forçar que uma propriedade tenha prioridade, ignorando estilos com maior força e prioridade, basta adicionar `!important` à propriedade:

```
nav a:hover {
    color: aqua !important;
}
```

**Veja:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <!--Bootstrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!--Fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--Stylesheet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <style>

body {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    margin: 0px;
}

/*----------Navbar----------*/

.container-fluid a:hover{
    color: rgb(26, 244, 183);
}

#navbar {
    background-color: rgb(46,41,58);
    margin: 0px;
}

.navbar, .navbar-default {
    border: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: aqua !important;
}

.navbar-nav {
    color: aqua;
}
        </style>
        <title>Teste</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div id="navbar" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Teste</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#indicadores">Indicadores</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#aprendizagem">Aprendizagem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#graficos">Gráficos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#simulador">Simulador</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#carteira">Carteira</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Registrar-se</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Entrar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <h3>Exemplo</h3>
            <p>Testando a página em Bootstrap</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deu certinho aqui, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

A solução seria está?

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: Seria bom você aprender a utilizar as ferramentas de debug dos navegadores, isso te ajuda a identificar quais seletores css estão afetando os elementos que você quer alterar

Comment: Funcionou amigo, valeu!