# Como fazer para usar a propriedade do arquivo CSS desejavel

Tags: css, propriedade, height

o elemento SELECT está "pegando" a propriedade height de um arquivo .css . Porém os Inputs "usam" essa mesma propriedade de outro arquivo css ( que é o arquivo ideal). E com isso a altura do SELECT fica menor do que o texto inserido no componente :
Na imagem o item 1 , SELECT está com a altura inferior ao da letra ( está cortando o texto )
O item 2 é o SELECT - class form-control
O item 3 mostra que a propriedade altura não está sendo utilizada ali no arquivo css
O item 4 mostra onde está sendo buscada a propriedade altura. 
Quando desmarco a altura do item 4 , então o componente fica com a altura OK. 
Como ffaço para usar a propriedade altura do arquivo css correto ? E por que isso acontece ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece devido a nivel hierarquico do CSS você vê isso neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143850/qual-seletor-css-tem-prioridade)

Você pode estar priorizando o heigth, utilizando a tag: `important` assim ele irá pegar o mais important para o código

ex:

```
.form-contro{
   heigth: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: DbaAlone , Obrigado ! Você sabe me dizer por que só o elemento SELECT foi "usar" a propriedade de outro arquivo ? Os inputs usaram do arquivo correto.

Comment: Então eles vem com presets do HTML5 & CSS3 entende? ai ele adota algumas formas, como por exemplo, quando você comeca um arquivo/ projeto, é nomal você zerar o padding e a margin entendeu?

Comment: Caso a minha resposta tenha ajudado ou resolvido, poderia confirmar e colcoar como resolvido o problema...

Comment: Sim, DbaAlone, resolveu e eu tinha marcado aquele "V' a esquerda ...blz.Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Seu `select` não tem o atributo `size` (:not[size]), nem o atributo `multiple` (:not[multiple]), por isso ele pega a altura indesejada.

Se vc colocar no seu `select` qualquer um esse atributos `size` e `multiple` a regra CSS indesejada deixa de ser aplicada, e ele volta a ficar com a altura padrão do `form-control`

Mas repare que seu `select` tem um `ID` já. E qualquer CSS declarado no `ID` tem preferencia, então um jeito fácil de resolver isso é colocando a altura no `ID` por exemplo. Veja um exemplo prático para entender.

```css
#teste {
 border: 1px solid #00f;
}
select.oi:not([xxx]):not([sss]) {
 border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
pega a cor do ID<br>
<select name="" id="teste" class="oi">
 <option value="123">123</option>
</select>
<br>
é zzz é xxx não pega o css<br>
<select name="" zzz xxx class="oi">
 <option value="123">123</option>
</select>
<br>
Não é zzz nem xxx então fica vermelho<br>
<select name="" class="oi">
 <option value="123">123</option>
</select>
```

*OBS: !important é empurrar a sujeira para debaixo do tape, lembre-se que agora tudo que usa a classe que tem !important vc não consegue mais mudar... isso pode te dar muita dor de cabeça se não souber o que está fazendo*

Comment: hugocsl, então se eu colocar a propriedade em questão ( height )  :  <select class="form-control" id="tipousuario" height> ele buscará a propriedade do arquivo css correto , ok ?

Comment: @RogerioRios olha o exemplo prático que eu coloquei na resposta, e leia o Link que o colega citou na outra resposta que vc vai entender melhor pq ele está pegando o estilo do .CSS "errado". Eu particularmente não recomendo usar !important, só em último casso mesmo, pq usando ele vc cria uma regra tão forte que vc não consegue mudar depois, além disso ele vai valer para todos elementos que tive a classe `.form-control`, inclusive alguma outra que vc já tenha mudado a altura

Comment: Retirei o !important , coloquei a propriedade height dentro :  <select class="form-control" id="tipousuario" height> . Não funcionou. Estou testando as opções que os parceiros estão postando.

Comment: @RogerioRios para usar `height` direto na tab vc tem que colocar na tag `style="height: 2.5rem"` por exemplo e não simplesmente escrever height na tag

Comment: Ok...hugocsl, mas colocar a propriedade direto na tag e não no arquivo css é indicado ? ( sou programador back-end e esse front-end tenho que estudar maaaaaisssssss rs )

Comment: @RogerioRios não, não é muito indicado coloca estilo CSS direto na tag, eu não recomendo. A não ser que na hora de publicar o projeto vc tenha algum tipo de webpack que pega o seu arquivo .css e transfira as propriedades direto para as tags html. Isso melhor a performance da requisição, carregamento da página etc. Mas isso é só pra produção, em desenvolvimento não recomendo.

Comment: #tipousuario{ 
    height: auto !important; } como o colega acima citou, funcionou , mas fica bem restrito, né ?

Comment: @RogerioRios como vc esta colocando o CSS usando o ID vc nem precisa do !important, provavelmente se vc deixar apenas `#tipousuario{ height: auto; } ` já vai ser suficiente.