# Sobreposiçao de tags no css

Tags: html, css

```
Css

/*O container envolve todos os elementos visiveis da pagina, OS container SAO IDS*/
#container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #CCC; 
  }
/*Define os estilos da caixa reutilizavel*/
.box p{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  }
/*Deixa o texto vermelho SOMENTE NOS PARAGRAFOS DENTRO DA CLASSE BOX*/
.box p{
  color: #F00;
  }
/*Deixa o texto cinza SOMENTE NOS PARAGRAFOS DO CONTAINER*/
#container p{
  color: #333;
  }
```

html

```
<div id="container">
  <p>This is our content area.</p>
  <div class="box">
    <p>I'm in a box</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p> I'm also in a box!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Minha duvida é porque o seletor "#conteiner p" que tem so a a especificação de cor se sobrepõem a o ".box p" só com a especificação de cor também, isso não esta contra a logica da cascata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seletor por id `#` tem prioridade sobre o seletor por classe `.`.

No seu caso, o seletor `.box p` term prioridade `0011` e o `#container p` tem prioridade `0101`, logo `101` é maior que `11`.

Existe um tópico a respeito disso **[aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143850/qual-seletor-css-tem-prioridade)**, cuja **[resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143893/8063)** informa até um **[site](https://specificity.keegan.st/)** onde você pode fazer esses cálculos.

Quando dois seletores possuem prioridade iguais, prevalecerá o que estiver escrito mais abaixo.

O conceito de "cascata" não tem a ver com isso. Pode ser assunto para um novo tópico, se já não o tiver no site.