# Porque a cor de fundo vermelha não está sendo aplicada no menu?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #main-menu ul {
            list-style: none;
            width: 200px;
        }

        #main-menu ul li {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        #main-menu ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #000000;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #selected-menu {
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="main-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="selected-menu" href="">Perfil</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Referências</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Configurações</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

No código acima tem um menu no qual tem a cor de fundo de preta no elemento `<a>` o que acontece é que eu coloquei um `id="selected-menu"` no primeiro elemento `<a>` e depois adicionei o seguinte código *CSS*:

```
    #selected-menu {
        background: red;
    }
```

E ele não muda a cor, ele só muda se eu usar `!important` na cor de fundo vermelha pelo contrário não acontece nada, porque isso está acontecendo?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #main-menu ul {
            list-style: none;
            width: 200px;
        }

        #main-menu ul li {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        #main-menu ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #000000;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #selected-menu {
            background: red !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="main-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="selected-menu" href="">Perfil</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Referências</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Configurações</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você já fez o teste em outras versões/navegadores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso se dá porque o seletor `#selected-menu` tem menos prioridade do que o seletor `#main-menu ul li a`. O `!important` irá fazer com que a propriedade dada no seletor sobreponha qualquer outra regra.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143893/8063) é explicado como calcular prioridades de seletores CSS. E [neste site](https://specificity.keegan.st/) você pode calcular online, que mostra que o seletor `#selected-menu` tem prioridade **100**, enquanto o `#main-menu ul li a` tem **103**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto, irá prevalecer o de valor **103** (o maior) onde você aplica o fundo preto aos links da lista.

Comment: Valeu, sam! : )

Answer (score -3):

Tente usar assim :

```
#selected-menu {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Fonte : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp