# Como transformar propriedades de um link em uma classe ou id específico?

Tags: html, css

Como consigo transformar as propriedades do link em uma class ou id?

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
```

consigo transforma-las em uma class e usar individualmente em algum elemento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa transformar nada, basta colocar o id ou classe no lugar da tag.

Exemplo

```
#cancel:hover      /* não precisa por a tag "a" */
.external:visited  /* e aqui, qualquer elemento com classe "external" que
                      tenha o estado "visited" será afetado               */
```

Veja no snippet:

```css
a {color:blue}         /* Vale para todos os links */
a:hover {color:green}  /* Vale para todos os links */
#b:hover {color:red}   /* Vale somente para o #b   */
```

```html
<a id="a">Hover genérico</a><br>
<a id="b">Hover diferente</a><br>
<a id="c">Hover genérico</a><br>
```

Comment: Certo, entendi, a minha dúvida surgiu diante que por exemplo, eu estar criando um menu e aplicando as propriedades do "a", ele aplica de uma forma geral, e na mesma página eu tenha um botão de "whatsapp" (img+link) fixo no canto inferior da tela, ele fica com essas propriedades aplicada também,  essa é minha dúvida na aplicação "individual"

Comment: é o mesmo caso do ítem com id #b, quando especifiquei individual no CSS, ele "passou por cima" do genérico por especificidade. [Mais detalhes neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143893/70)

Comment: Então como fica a estrutura do #b para aplicar diferentes cores para hover e visited por exemplo?

Comment: Mesma coisa, faz um `#b:visited` tambem (e um `#b:active`, etc).

Comment: Ah, não sabia que poderia ter mais de uma id com o mesmo nome xD, obrigado!

Comment: CSS é cumulativo. Se fizer numa linha #b {color:red} e na outra #b {font-size:76px} ambas as características funcionarão (leia o [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143893/70) que passei no segundo comentário para saber a ordem de aplicação) - Ainda, #b:active e #b:hover são definições diferentes, aumentando a especificidade (conforme link já mencionado). A sugestão é você fazer experiências diversas, não se limite a tentar as coisas só quando precisar usar de fato.