# Tem como usar display block e flex juntos?

Tags: css

Recentemente vi um Indiano fazer um menu de navegação usando HTML,CSS,JS mas oque me intrigou foi ele usar `display: block` e `display: flex` no mesmo elemento. Talvez ele errou porque até então eu sei que o último a ser declarado é oque recebe a aplicação. Eu até fiz testes mas o último sempre é aplicado!

Então fica a pergunta: é possível usar esses 2 display no mesmo elemento?

Comment: No mesmo elemento não tem como. Atributos repetidos seguem a [regra da especificidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143893/100416) para definir qual será utilizado. Você pode ver isso pelo "inspecionar elemento" também.

Comment: O `display` tem duas variantes, uma para dentro e outra para fora. O que quero dizer é que um elemento que recebe uma propriedade de display pode afetar como os filhos se comportam, e/ou como ele mesmo se comporta em relação aos elementos adjacentes. Um exemplo disso é o `display: inline-flex` esse display deixa o elementos com display inline em relação aos irmãos, mas os filhos se comportam como se o pai fosse flex. Resumindo, o elemento passa a ser inline para fora e flex para dentro ao mesmo tempo. Mas duas propriedade de display no mesmo elemento, a que vier por último subscreve a anterior

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Antes de saber se é possível ou não devemos saber o que faz cada um, seja **Block** ou **Flex**

> #### O que faz o `display: block`?
>
> Faz com que o elemento HTML seja renderizado como **bloco** tal com os parágrafos e os cabeçalhos são.

Exemplo de aplicação na página abaixo:

[image]

<sup>Demonstração de como é exibido o estilo bloco na página.</sup>

> #### O que faz o `display: flex`?
>
> É um recurso do CSS3 que serve para "moldar" e/ou organizar elementos em *containers* de forma flexível conforme a sua necessidade.

Exemplo de aplicação na página abaixo:

[image]

---

### Afinal da para usar ambas propriedades juntas?

**Não é possível utiliza-los no mesmo elemento juntamente**. Atributos repetidos seguem a [regra da especificidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143850/qual-seletor-css-tem-prioridade/143893#143893) para dizer qual será utilizado. Como o usuário @Rafael Tavares mencionou, podes visualizar claramente pelo *DevTools* (ou Inspencionador de Elementos do Navegador)