# slideToggle(); para linha em tabelas

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});



<div id="flip"><table><td>Maria</td></table></div>
<div id="panel"><table><td>1.000</td></table></div>

<div id="flip"><table><td>José</td></table></div>
<div id="panel"><table><td>2.000</td></table></div>
```

Seguindo o código acima, eu preciso clicar em Maria e aparecer o valor abaixo (1.000), e o mesmo com José. Está funcionando perfeitamente quando clica em Maria, mas não para José. Como soluciono este problema?

Comment: Você está utilizando `id` que é um identificador único e somente o primeiro elemento encontrado no documento é selecionado, tente mudar para classe, exemplo `<div class="flip"></div>` e `$('.flip')` relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39875/qual-a-prioridade-do-html-id-ou-class/39879#39879

Comment: A diferença é que o meu original, ele oculta o linha debaixo e só quando clicada, ela aparece, e a sua edição faz ao contrário.

Comment: Veja a resposta, se é isso que pretende, veja que adicionei um `$(this).next('.panel')` para selecionar o próximo elemento, ou seja o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando id que é um identificador único e somente o primeiro elemento encontrado no documento é selecionado, tente mudar para classe, exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.flip{
  background-color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.panel{
  background-color:blue;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip"><table><td>Maria</td></table></div>
<div class="panel"><table><td>1.000</td></table></div>

<div class="flip"><table><td>José</td></table></div>
<div class="panel"><table><td>2.000</td></table></div>
```

Comment: PERFEITO. Funcionou. Eu gostaria de saber, como deixar a linha com os números ocultas quando carrega a pagina e só apareça se clicado. O caminho inverso da tua alteração. Tem como?

Comment: @RafaelBrito tem sim, basta adicionar a propriedade `display:none` na classe `.panel` do CSS.

Comment: 100% AGORA. muito obrigado.