# O rádio button está se comportando como checkbox e não permite selecionar ou desmarcar a opção

Tags: javascript, html, radiobutton

```js
function transformar(){  
    var converter = parseFloat(document.getElementById('converter').value);
    var resposta = document.getElementById('resposta');
    var resp = '';
    

    
    if(document.getElementById('celsius').checked){
        resp = (converter - 32) * (5/9);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('fahren').checked){
        resp = (converter * (9/5)+32);
    }
    resposta.innerHTML = resp;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temperatura</title>
    <script src="temperatura.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Graus Celsius: <input type="radio" id="celsius">
        Graus Fahrenheit: <input type="radio" id="fahren"> <br>
        Converter Valor: <input type="number" id="converter">
        <button onclick="transformar()">transformar</button><br>
        Resposta:
        <div id="resposta"></div>
    </form>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você ter um grupo de botões de rádio, ou seja, que permitem que um botão ligado desligue o outro você tem que dar o mesmo nome para todos os elementos desse grupo. Seu código sequer tem um nome (`name`), ele assume o mesmo do `id`,   e não tem valor (`value` que é um *label* para o botão), ele assume o `id`, mas fica feio porque é o nome de um identificador e não um texto representativo. Sem o mesmo nome cada botão é independente e não tem o que desligar já que ele é único, você tem dois *radio button* distintos com um botão cada.

Veja mais sobre o uso de `id` em [Qual a prioridade do HTML? "id" ou "class"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39875/101). Use-o de forma adequada e não deixe ele ser um coringa para tudo.

HTML é muito permissivo, agrada programadores inexperientes porque funciona, apesar de estar errado. Quase todos os códigos HTML que vejo em perguntas aqui são mal escritos porque não consideram como é o correto funcionamento dele, apenas há a preocupação se está funcionando. Neste caso deu sorte porque nem funcionou  e  não fez algo errado inadvertidamente.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Tem outras coisas ruins neste código. Consertei só o problema que está na pergunta, fica para você o exercício de consertar outras partes. Assim funciona:

```js
function transformar(){  
    var converter = parseFloat(document.getElementById('converter').value);
    var resposta = document.getElementById('resposta');
    var resp = '';
    

    
    if(document.getElementById('celsius').checked){
        resp = (converter - 32) * (5/9);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('fahren').checked){
        resp = (converter * (9/5)+32);
    }
    resposta.innerHTML = resp;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temperatura</title>
    <script src="temperatura.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Graus Celsius: <input type="radio" id="celsius" name="temperatura" value="Celsius">
        Graus Fahrenheit: <input type="radio" id="fahren" name="temperatura" value="Fahrenheit"> <br>
        Converter Valor: <input type="number" id="converter">
        <button onclick="transformar()">transformar</button><br>
        Resposta:
        <div id="resposta"></div>
    </form>
        
</body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/RadioButton.js).